# Add VisitedDays to database schema

Tags: feature-request, database

I visited StackOverflow over (more than) 801 days and would like to know if I'm the most active one, after all others. So it should be possible to get the visited days of each user on the [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new)?? Not too hard to implement, I think.

Comment: Nice, but that's [hardly a record](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122976/295232).

Comment: There's just the problem of lies though

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143842/record-for-most-consecutive-days-visited