# Fix description for Enthusiast and Fanatic badges

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-description

Each [badge description](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges) with a single sentence doesn't contain a dot. Except for *Enthusiast* and *Fanatic* badges:

> [image: Badges]

I think those descriptions for *Enthusiast* and *Fanatic* badges should be changed from the current form:

> Visit the site each day for {N} consecutive days. (Days are counted in UTC.)

to non-dot form:

> Visit the site each day for {N} consecutive days (days are counted in UTC)

or even more short version:

> Visit the site each day for {N} consecutive days (counted in UTC)

for the consistency with another descriptions on the badges page.

Seems the inconsistency has been appear after accepting that FR: [Add 'UTC' to description to 'fanatic' badge description](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155732/add-utc-to-description-to-fanatic-badge-description?rq=1)

Comment: Or just plain remove the parentheses if they want two sentences

Comment: The tag badges also have a dot (period).

Comment: Oh, you notice things a bit too much. ;)