# Make UTC link in badge description translatable

Tags: feature-request, localization, russian-stackoverflow, badge-description, transifex

Recently I changed translations in descriptions for *Fanatic* and *Enthusiast* badges on Stack Overflow in Russian according to my [global wide feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300444/339911):

> [image: Descriptions]

Now I noticed that UTC link in the descriptions refers to [wikipedia article in English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

Is it possible to make such link translatable via Transifex, so every localized site could use language specific link here?