# Links in the footer in international sites should allow to point to translated pages

Tags: support, footer, internationalization, translations, international-sites

We have found a "problem" in [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com). (I also think it would be the same in all international sites)

In the footer of the site we can find this text:

> diseño del sitio / logo © 2018 Stack Exchange Inc; contribuciones de usuarios licenciadas bajo [cc by-sa 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) con [atribución requerida](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/). rev 2018.10.9.31885

This is the translated version of

> site design / logo © 2018 Stack Exchange Inc; user contributions licensed under [cc by-sa 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) with [attribution required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/). rev 2018.10.9.31885

we can find all across the Stack Exchange sites.

The problem is we'd like to change the two links in that text to links of the Spanish versions. But they seem to be placeholders in Transifex that are changed to the link itself in the codebehind.

Is there any way we could achieve this? Why are those links placeholders and can't be changed?

The other option we have is to eliminate the placeholders and put those links manually, but we'd like that to be the last resort.

---

Link to the string in [traducir.win](https://github.com/g3rv4/Traducir/blob/master/README.md): https://traducir.win/string/4633

Link to the string in Transifex: https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/translate/#es/english/138357673?key=86ac80122f60c079a677f2b25e9955b1

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure that the first link to "cc by-sa 3.0" should be allowed to change on localized sites. Because this is the first place and source of the license text. It can be changed only in one case if Creative Commons will add Spanish version on their site.

The second link which is currently refers to the stackoverlow blog should be definitely allowed to customize for localized sites. Such link looks same as many other links from the site help sections, many of which have translated versions (at least for Stack Overflow in Russian, where I came here).

BTW, I also have a request (not satisfied yet) to change a hardcoded link in badge description: [Make UTC link in badge description translatable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300519/339911)

Maybe you could like to use your own link for that case too.

Comment: Well, [there is a spanish version of cc by-sa 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.es). About the second, we have translated that in a meta post and would like to link to it

Comment: @Pikoh I didn't know about Spanish version of cc. Unfortunately there is no Russian version :(

Comment: are you sure? I think there is,try the language combo in the page linked. There are a lot of languages there... :)

Comment: @Pikoh A lot, but no Russian yet.

Comment: Wow, thats weird.Anyway (if my proposal is satisfied) you could link to https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/deed.ru (it's still in english, but may be translated anytime in the future)