# Max consecutive days in profile

Tags: feature-request, consecutive-days

Is there any opinion on adding a max consecutive days count to the user profile? I recently got a fanatic badge, but I kept consecutively visiting the site for a long time after I got the badge, and I was just curious about the maximum number days I've consecutively visited the site, as I wasn't able to check that after the consecutive days counter reset.

Comment: Why? It's like a fun little contest against yourself. And, these guys: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122976/anyone-with-a-visited-1000-days-1000-consecutive-in-his-her-profile

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Visiting the site for 100 consecutive days is hard, and once you've visited that many days in a row, it can become a bit of an addiction.  Every now and then, I take a break and go do other things for awhile, as real life begins to miss me.

Encouraging people to visit for 30 consecutive days or 100 consecutive days has some real benefits. During this time, people will likely find something interesting to answer, ask, upvote, downvote, or comment on. Most people who visit a site consecutively for 100 days *will end up doing something positive on the site.*

But doing more to encourage addictive, obsessive compulsive behavior may not be helpful in the long run, and the benefits gained from implementing such a feature are negligible.

If the only thing keeping someone visiting after 100 consecutive days is an obsession with the consecutive visits counter, then something might be wrong. Most people, after 100 days, become healthy Stack Exchange contributors who visit regularly, have gained an understanding of how the site works, and participate in the process. At the 100 day point, if someone isn't intrinsically motivated to visit the site, then encouraging them to visit more may not really benefit anyone, including the person obsessively watching the counter.

With that said, there are folks like [Bill and VonC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122976/anyone-with-a-visited-1000-days-1000-consecutive-in-his-her-profile) who have visits in the thousands. Perhaps it's not good for us to try and keep up with them. Bill is a busy Stack Overflow moderator, and VonC is one of the users on the top page on Stack Overflow. So, their visits aren't due to watching the counter. It's because they're both heavily involved in the process itself and have been so since the very beginning.

Although not directly related to the consecutive days counter, here's an example of where the process does sometimes fail:

This user, [yibe](https://stackexchange.com/users/145766/yibe?tab=accounts), has the gold Fanatic badge on just about every site on the network. But this user hasn't contributed content to most of them and hasn't visited since earning the badge. I'm glad 100 is the limit so this poor user can move on and hopefully find something constructive to do. :)