# Any thoughts on a semidecadian badge for people with five years service and an average of N points per year?

Tags: discussion, badges, badge-request

Given that Stack Overflow is close to its fifth birthday as a public site, has any thought been given to a 'semidecadian' badge for people who have:

- been registered with the site five years (a semi-decade, hence the name),
- scored more than N points per year on average (where N might be 1000).

The idea behind 'average of N points per year' is to allow slow starters to gain the badge eventually, rather than ruling them out in year 1.  The details are obviously subject to tweaking.

This might be a gold badge (the platinum version would be the decadian badge, with a larger value of N required — and no-one eligible for another 5 years or so).

These would complement the current Yearling badge (which is silver).

Comment: Frankly if yearling is silver this has to be gold

Comment: I think that gold badge for five yearlings in a row would be enough and more simple, pretty similar to Fanatic which is given for being consistent member.

Comment: Should be a platinum/diamond badge for a "yearling" of consecutive days first...

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd the problem is yearling will award based on rep averaged over x years and not rep per year.  I could create an account, leave for 4.5 years, and in that last 6 months, earn 1000 rep and get 5 yearling badges in a row.  I don't necessarily think that accomplishment is worth a gold badge.

Comment: @psubsee2003: Yeah, but you'd have to have a good memory, and a better-than-Twitter attention span.  Maybe that's deserving of a gold badge.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I didn't necessarily mean doing that intentionally.... I just meant doing it more or less by accident.  I just think if it were the gold version of the Yearling badge, you should some show consistent dedication to the site.  I think the "N" should be higher than 200/year for 5 straight years.

Comment: @RichardTingle: Agreed — proposal adjusted.  To a large extent, I regard the details as 'up to the Stack Exchange team'; the basic idea is recognizing 5 years contributions — at somewhat more than the 'yearling' badge level of effort on average, at least (and I won't be upset if it is 1000 points each year rather than on average).

Comment: @JonClements "Should be a platinum/diamond badge for a "yearling" of consecutive days first": I agree. (http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122976/6309). 1573 consecutive days (with at least one answer posted). And counting.

Comment: I've been up over 700 days consecutive (not absolutely sure that there was an answer each day — but probably) a couple of times, but each time I then went visiting overseas and ended up not being able to connect for a period of over 24 hours, breaking my sequence (APs who can't remember their wifi password — grrrrr!!!).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is my proposal on how the loyalty and commitment gold badge could be:

**Lustrum badge will be given to people that have 5 consecutive `Yearling` badges and have an overall score over 3k** (or 5k or 10k the best amount could be decided here). In any case the score should be higher than the 1k that is necessary for the 5 consecutive `Yearling` badges.

The badge could look like this:

[image]

I went for the word lustrum since I think it sounds good(at least better than [semidecadian](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196659/any-thoughts-on-a-semidecadian-badge-for-people-with-five-years-service-and-an-a) or quinquennium) and represent 5 years in one word.

[image]

Also **this could be awarded multiple times** much like `Yearling`, thus in 2018 on stackoverflow there could be people that qualify for two `Lustrum`  badges.

Comment: "over 5 consecutive Yearling badges" so you can't earn the Lustrum badge until you've already earned 6 Yearling badges, AKA you really only earn it on your 7th anniversary?

Comment: @TylerH Fixed it thanks

Answer (score 10):

The name for such a badge doesn't have to convey "5 years"; the duration is just a criterion, as is the points threshold.

I think a better name is "Veteran", which would look like:

[image]

"Veteran" better conveys the meaning and significance of the achievement, without necessarily conveying the quanta used to determine it.

---

Regarding the points requirement, consider at least 1K (maybe 2K) in a year to make that year count towards the badge, rather than an *average* per year which could lead to people briefly using a old, even dormant, account to crank out 1K in a couple of weeks to game the badge.

Answer (score 9):

My biggest beef with this proposal (apart from the time I'd have to wait :-) is the name!

Decadian? I'm not sure. This question was the only page on Google that mentioned it.

Taking centenarians, nonagenarians etc I'd have thought we'd be looking more at the Latin root, so decemenarians?

However, after internetzing some people ([1](http://theelderlies.wordpress.com/2006/10/02/age-by-decade/), [2](http://theelderlies.wordpress.com/2006/10/02/age-by-decade/)) agree with each other (probably because they cribbed it) that someone between 10 and 19 is a denarian. Though dictionary.com and my copy of the OED don't have it, [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/denarian) (not the most reliable source) also agrees. It doesn't seem to be much used, though the form for 20-29 proposed by these sites (vicenarian) seems to be widely used, which makes them seem more trustworthy.

Apparently the progression as follows<sup>1</sup>

> denarian
> vicenarian
> tricenarian
> quadragenarian
> quinquagenarian
> sexagenarian
> septuagenarian
> octogenarian
> nonagenarian
> centenarian

So, Semi-denarian? Extensible! See yourself as a quinquagenarian SE member!

<sub>1. Everything has the same but this was officially copied from the linked Wiktionary page to avoid copyright issues :-).</sub>

Comment: ***Decadent***, of course.

Comment: @Gilles wrong math. Divide by two - semi[decadent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decadent_movement)

Comment: Will you be demi-decadent or semi-decadent @Giles :-)?

Comment: @gnat But using words that say what they mean is so… what's the opposite of decadent? Let's just say passé.

Comment: I'm somewhat attached to the idea (not least because I'm at 4 y 11 m at the moment) — but the name is infinitely fungible.  If it's to be a fun name, I'd go with 'semi-decadent' at the moment — but I have no qualms about a 'semidenarian' since it seems to have better Latin linguistic roots.  I didn't bother to look and see whether I was creating a new word — it sounded apposite and didn't need a lot of explaining.

Comment: @Gilles _what's the opposite of decadent_ would make a fun question at EL&U.SE (can't guarantee it would be compliant with their rules though)

Comment: I suppose the proper term for 'every five years' is [_quinquennial_](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quinquennial), and then there's [_quinquennium_](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quinquennium) for a specific period of five years.  The _quinquennialist_ badge, perhaps?

Comment: What happened with this proposal ?