# Award Constable and Sheriff badges multiple times, once per full year

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges

We have two badges for moderators: Constable for being a moderator during Beta (for one year or through graduation), and Sheriff for being an elected moderator (for a year) on a full site.
These badges are awarded once per user, after the criteria have been met.

I propose that the badges be awarded repeatedly, i.e. for every full year served.
Rationale:

- Being moderator for five years plus arguably warrant more recognition than being such for a single year before abdicating.
- The only other time-based badge, Yearling, is awarded repeatedly as well.

Comment: So you are after some badges? ;) No, seriously: good request.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Of course! If there's no badges, why do the job at all? ;)

Comment: Although I am not a mod, I agree with this - especially with your point that `eing moderator for five years plus arguably warrant more recognition than being such for a single year before abdicating`

Comment: I like it. This would similar to the situation for the Socratic badge, right?

Answer (score 12):

I agree with this. Serving a whole year as moderator of a site is certainly worth recognition. A repeating gold badge would be nice for this. And I'd wager it wouldn't be hard to implement either :)

Maybe someone from SE could give an authoritative answer as to whether or not they are considering this?

Answer (score -3):

Or, what about different/new badges for *milestones*?

I like your idea, and it would work having 3 "Constable/Sheriff" badges after being here 3 years, but another idea would be to have something like:

- Year 1 (only) - Constable/Sheriff badges
- Year 3 (only) - New badges (need naming/thinking up)
- Year 5 (only) - New badges (need naming/thinking up, different to year
  3)

Then rather than recognition for being a mod for 3 years is you have "3" Constable/Sheriff badges and someone else only has "2", you actually have an entirely different badge only earned for being a mod for 3 years.

---

EDIT in response to comments

If we only award the same badge each year, someone who's been a moderator for 8 years has the *same badge type* as a moderator only in their 2nd year. Not much to showcase really is it?

Sure, their "count" is different (total 8 badges VS 2 badges) but it's devalued having the same badge type.

Alternatively, having a badge *type* which can only be earned after being here X years stands out more as a *medal of honour*.
At glance, users can see "ooh, they've got the *mega-mod* badge"..

(yeah, "mega-mod" badge, is just for sake of an example..)

Comment: The original idea is good because it is simple and perpetual. Here, you'd have to keep adding badges every couple years for the long-serving mods, or else it wouldn't be fair.

Comment: "*Here, you'd have to keep adding badges every couple years for the long-serving mod*" I don't see that as a  problem. milestones could move to every 5 years: 5 years, 10 years, 15 years, 20 years then just repeat whichever the last one is. Also, there is no "fairness" in badges, they are what they are. If they exist you can earn one. Is it not "fair" I cannot possibly earn a moderator badge?

Comment: I disagree. We don't have different Great Answer, Populist, Famous Question, etc. badges.

Comment: In 8 years a mod will have 8 "Constable/Sheriff" badges - is 8 of the same badges really a representative of a thank you or achievement? Or is it just 7 of the *same thing* you already earned?

Comment: Similar to what is suggested [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196659/266359)?

Comment: I think "Sheriff x 8" is way more cool than new badges -it shows the dedication at a glance.

Comment: @MonicaCellio There is that argument, yes. I just think someone who's been a mod for (e.g.) 5 or 8 years should have a more distinguishable badge than the same one as someone who's been a mod for 1 year.

Comment: Well, I've only been a mod for three, but FWIW *I* think the multiples are cooler. Just one opinion.