# Stack Exchange activity tab not sending me to URL with #comment

Tags: bug, comments, stackexchange.com

These do not take me directly to the comment.

[image]

These do.

[image]

Why?

Comment: As far as I can tell, they all take you to the post the comment is on, not the comment itself. If you're linked to the comment, it's the very top thing on the page. That's not the case with any of those links - try this one as an example - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122976/anyone-with-a-visited-4444-days-4444-consecutive-in-their-profile#comment1089361_333549 The difference with that first comment is that it's on an answer, so it jumps to the answer but it's still linking to the post, not the comment.

Comment: @Catija Oh yes, you are correct. I've mistaken the functionality. However, why don't these links take you to the comment directly?

Comment: If I had to guess, the comment isn't much use without the context it's posted in, so we went with the post rather than the comment directly.

Comment: @Catija If you visit your profile's activity tab in a specific stack site then it does take you to the comment directly. I guess it's just a discrepancy more than anything else.

Comment: Yeah - Heck, for all I know, [we added the ability to link to a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5436/direct-link-to-a-comment) after that page was created - so it was coded to go to the post because that's the best we could do at the time. The network profiles haven't gotten much love in a long while. :)

Comment: It must be both a blessing and a curse to cater to a user-based which is predominantly programmers =)

Comment: HAHAHA For me, in particular, it's hard because I'm not a programmer, so I can end up knee deep in people telling me what is and isn't possible with no way for me to actually judge if those statements are accurate!

Comment: MonkeyZeus, confirmed. It seems that "Accepts", "Posts", and 'Badges" [link correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwCYP.png) and you *arrive* where you would expect. The "Comments", "Revisions", and "Reviews" lack the correct link.