# May we have some more SO stickers, please?

Tags: discussion, stickers

I realize we *did* receive some stickers before, but I believe more stickers would be tolerated. Of course, you should *deserve* them first. Are there any possible sticker competitions?

Comment: The sticker factory shut down because of the government shutdown - you're out of luck

Comment: I think we should all (ab)use the answer box to indicate where we would stick our SO stickers.

Comment: I was promised stickers for the survey (a year or so back?) but never got any. Pout pout. =(

Comment: I want a "closed as off-topic" sticker.  If someone is talking too much about nothing, I'll stick it over their mouth.

Comment: @Jamal Stack Exchange, Inc. disclaims all responsibility for acts of violence -- physical, psychological or otherwise -- performed against your person, your friends' persons, your or their family members' persons, or your or their property, resulting from this or similar stickings. (Phew, close one. You can thank me later, legal team.)

Comment: Sticker with your personal flair would be cool. ;)

Comment: @Sha With auto-update every day.

Comment: *\*upvotes question and every answer, because I want stickers\**

Comment: I've still got spare stickers. Right now I'd be much keener about that coffee mug, and I'd even review a large part of the close queue for one...

Comment: I think it would be nice if there was a User-friendly "sticker-request" page, where you can pay like $1.00 or so to request them?

Comment: @Szymon Just having a lil' fun! STICKER

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> Historical note: in its early days, Stack Overflow provided stickers to anyone willing to send a self-addressed, stamped envelope to the office. This is no longer the case; official statement follows.

Stack Overflow does not currently provide stickers upon request. While we do have stickers, they're printed primarily for top-user swag and promotional event purposes.

Comment: Can I get several of them to plug the hole in my ceiling?

Comment: Be sure to check your local building codes and verify the structural integrity of the ceiling after patching. Maybe ask on [diy.se].

Comment: I can vouch for this.  I sent in a self-addressed stamped envelope and got some, what I assume are stickers. :-)

Comment: I have extra stamps, and will take you guys up on the offer. REPEATEDLY!!! :>

Comment: If you use one of [these physical mail services](https://www.google.com/search?q=send+physical+mail+online) (I tried mailaletter.com), they will send a SASE for you. It's kind of pricey compared to a couple stamps, but the benefit is that you don't have to get up from your computer!

Comment: Quick update: I just got my SO stickers. mailaletter.com worked fine (although boy is snail mail slow!)

Comment: @beporter -  how long did it take? i'm antsy for mine

Comment: @Adel I don't remember exactly. The time stamps on my comments above suggest somewhere around 3-4 weeks? There are humans involved on the other end, so the result could be pretty variable I guess.

Comment: Trying mailaletter.com from Europe right now, I'll report back when I hear back!

Comment: Reporting back, earlier than I expected; I received the stickers yesterday, 2015-03-24, after sending a SASE via the internet. The future is now.

Comment: @Joost how did you do? on the mailaletter.com user guide they say that return enveloppes for addresses outside the United States do not have postage.

Comment: @PierrOz Hmm, I see now. I had not even looked that far, initially, and just gave it a shot. I suppose the SE staff might have stuck a stamp on it themselves, then.. No guarantees!

Answer (score 49):

I second this.  I want stickers.  SO MANY STICKERS.

What would I do with said stickers, you ask?  I would place them

- on my laptop,
- on-or-around my cubicle at work, and
- on my coworkers (probably on their backs, while they're not looking).

I think this promotes Stack Overflow and the Stack Exchange network in a positive and professional way.

Comment: Ooh ooh, or you can stick them on .... ah never mind... you said professional...

Comment: @Bart: It's professional if you get paid for it!

Comment: It's the world's oldest profession.  ...Putting stickers on people, that is.

Comment: @jadarnel27 yes, in ancient Babylon it was all the craze!

Answer (score 46):

STICKERS!!!

Where would I place stickers?

- My laptop, top and bottom (it's too thin to put them on the sides)
- Every door I see (because people couldn't help seeing them as they open the door)
- My car (because I go a lot of places)
- Other peoples' cars (because they might go a lot of places)
- The back of my TI-84 (the buttons and screen are on the front)
- My cat
- Random places in Wal-Mart (because lots of people go to wal-marts)
- My ceiling fan (because everyone looks at ceiling fans)
- Random light bulbs (because then you would have to look at the sticker to remove it so you can see)
- Inside red freehand circles (because that's where they originated)
- On waffle makers (because then I would want to make more waffles)

Comment: When I saw "my car," I thought it said "my cat" for a second. Then I realized I was being ridiculous. Then I kept reading.

Answer (score 21):

I also want stickers!

I'm going on a canoe trip tomorrow, and it would be amazing if I could place a Stack Overflow sticker on the canoe to advertise to all the tech-savvy wild animals I'm likely to see.

Although, it seems this could become a bit of a *sticking point*, after all the previous ones were a little *tacky*. As long as SO *adheres* to proper techniques they should be able to avoid getting in a *bind*.

Comment: I think with a bit of work you could throw [some more](http://www.synonym.com/synonyms/stick/) puns in there. Four is not nearly enough.

Comment: I hope that you dramatically put on sunglasses prior to each of the italicized words.

Comment: @jadarnel27 Actually, I take off a pair :)

Comment: http://mirrors.rit.edu/instantCSI/

Answer (score 19):

I only joined this network because of this, published on Jan 20 '12

> [image]

I thought "Yes, I want stickers", so worked my way to the first page. Now, almost two years later, here I am, [all addicted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157449/185667), no stickers o_Ø

Comment: It has been warned by authorities that WordPress is a gateway drug to real programming. It lures you in with stickers and plugins only to deceive you into craving real design patterns and a language that doesn't suck. Beware the siren's call before you end up on an arduous journey seeking Pythonic nirvana.

Comment: ZOMG, no! I like it simple and praise all you folks that sail patterns among sirens. Namaste, Python!

Comment: AFAIK this is a onetime event on site graduation.

Answer (score 11):

Stickers!!!

yes please, they would be immeasurably handy for patching the hole in my roof whilst providing a visual advertisement to visiting friends, relatives, wildebeest and repairmen.

I travel to many conferences (scientific and technical) and teach senior students - it would be a great way of spreading the word throughout my professional activities.

I'd be able to stick them all over my dad to convince him to join!