# Stickers still available?

Tags: discussion, stickers

Does anyone know if this is still a valid link? Can I still send an envelope to the address to get stickers?

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/09/how-to-get-stack-overflow-stickers/

I can't find anything **recent** about it.

Comment: 2 months ago: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/203189/172011

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, stickers are still available, as per the **[link presented in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/203189/172011)** (from two months ago):

> As described in this now-ancient blog post you can get yourself some
>   stickers by just sending us a Self-Addressed Stamped Envelope. We'll
>   put some Stack Exchange stickers in it and send it back.

Comment: Note - *for best results*, enclose a short note listing the sites that you really enjoy. We don't have stickers for _every_ site in the NY office, but we do have quite a few and will try to get you a few that you'd really appreciate (up to postage limits - so an extra stamp isn't a bad idea either.).