# How can a fan get swag / promotional gifts without any challenge or high reputation score?

Tags: support, swag

Today is my 51st day on Stack Overflow and I am a huge fan of SO/SE.

Yesterday on Twitter I read about SE swag / promotional gifts and I really fell in love with it.

Is there a way to get this swag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get some [stickers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212908/245360) if that will do. All other promotional stuff is given with some special occasions (like [reaching 100](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287851/replacement-for-broken-mug/287855#287855)K) and events (like the [10M question swag](https://stackoverflow.com/10m), [writing stories](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271359/choose-your-own-swag-the-craziest-contest-idea-ever-what-were-we-thinking), or even [drawing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213769/work-is-hard-lets-color-the-walls)).

There used to be a store, but that [went down years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137579/what-happened-to-the-stack-exchange-store). So the only way to get some swag is searching for it on eBay or so.

Comment: Thank you so much Sir, I think it will take almost 4 to 5 years to reaching this milestone

Comment: @Saurabh not really, just wait until December, there is usually some kind of event going on with swag.

Comment: @ShadowWizard..Thank you !

Comment: How would i know about this in future??? @ShadowWizard

Comment: @Saurabh just follow this site during December and you will see. I will let you know here, if I won't forget. :)