# Replacement for broken mug?

Tags: support, merchandise

My Stack Overflow mug suffered a tragic mishap. Is there any way to get a replacement?

[image: Broken mug]

Comment: I expect you get suspended for at least a week 'to cool down'. Man... How did this get that far?

Comment: If this is off-topic here, where should I ask? (I've tried e-mail.)

Comment: Re "I've tried e-mail", how long ago? Did they tell you to post here or have you just not gotten an answer yet?

Comment: In Feb 2015, I got an e-mail from a Stack Exchange Community Manager asking me where to send a box of cool stuff. On November 30, after the mug was broken, I replied to the same person asking about a replacement. I haven't gotten a response. I've seen other posts here about obtaining mugs; if such questions are off-topic, perhaps the "merchandise" tag shouldn't exist.

Comment: Buying a new one would be the best option but the problem with that is that SE doesn't sell things any more. Personally, I wouldn't expect a company to replace something they gave me for free, spending their own time and cost to send it.

Comment: @Catija: I'm not asking for a *free* replacement. I'm also willing to accept "no" as the answer.

Comment: @Erik too much manpower. Though with the rise of print-on-demand shops, maybe they will reconsider someday. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137579/284336

Comment: You've now learned that not all casts are safe.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

All of our mugs that go out with 100k and 250k swag packages come with a limited lifetime warranty! Not really, but we appreciate you all enough that we'd happily replace it if it gets lost or broken.

We do have your support ticket requesting a new one - we're just a bit backlogged at the moment and are pretty much ignoring swag temporarily until we knock down the backlog.

Comment: ... there's a 250K swag package? Damnit, now I got something else to aspire to once I hit 100K...

Comment: Oh, what about mugs obtained in different ways, e.g. writing a story? ;)

Comment: I got the new one a couple of days ago. Thanks again!