# There should be system to send users gifts like free stickers

Tags: discussion, feature-request, swag

There should be some system to send small gifts to users on some criteria.
Gift should include stickers and other things.
Stack over flow should email user and ask them to provide address to send a gift.

Criteria can be

1. User who pass some reputation like 700 or 500.
2. Who opens the site etc

Even on badges etc.
Also it should not be that hard to get the gift specially stickers :) so it can be done.

Its a suggestion as I love Stack Over Flow <3

Comment: You haven't really said *why*. As Q&A site you get rewards in the form of knowledge. And you also get some bigger numbers next to your name. And occasionally some bronze/silver/gold blobs, also with some numbers next to them. Why should people get physical stickers? Why is that better than the current system?

Comment: It will cost millions of dollars to SE. I prefer their money spent on new features, and fixing of bugs

Comment: There are 88042 users [with more than 1000 reputation](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/393718/users-with-more-than-x-reputation?reputation=1000), and 968 with [more than 50000](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/393718/users-with-more-than-x-reputation?reputation=50000) - it's really not feasible to send all of them gifts. The numbers are just too high.

Comment: @ShadowWizard the users can be filtered out. most active users or who spend 4-5 hours a day of any other thing most users will be filtered out

Comment: @Shan here on Meta is just means 11 users disagree with what you suggest. Nothing personal, and it doesn't mean the idea on its own isn't well thought or something like that.

Comment: @ShadowWizard yes i know 11 users disagree but at the end it affects the reputation. After putting a huge time on Stack over flow daily i though to post a first question here and it cost me alot. (-22 points)

Comment: @Shan one decent answer with meager 3 upvotes and you compensate for this, and gain some. So, not the end of the world. :)

Comment: @shan it just means you have to really think through your ideas before you throw them in. Check the simple calculations of Shadow Wizard and you will see it isn't feasible.

Comment: @PatrickHofman yes i have checked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is already a possibility to [request some stickers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/203189/245360), but it will cost you money.

Sending stuff for free feels like charity to me, and SE is not a charity. They are trying to make some money, not spend it all on stickers. If you posted something in the special posts for the 10 millionth question, you could get some swag, but those events are exceptions.

Sending gifts for merely receiving a badge or a very low amount of reputation seems pointless to me. Not to speak about the number of employees needed to arrange all this.

Answer (score 6):

SE sends gifts to people occasionally, for major milestones or for contests.  Recently Stack Overflow celebrated its ten-millionth question and there were opportunities to get goodies related to that.  When a beta site graduates and gets its design, top users (about 72 of them) get bundles of swag.  Users who reach 100k reputation get something.  Moderators get t-shirts as thanks for volunteering their time.

Even these levels of swag-sending take the staff a fair bit of time; I know because I've talked with them about it (in the course of sorting out a missing package).  You're proposing adding a *lot* of work, and I don't see the benefit.  Better would be to lobby SE to set up a store where you could just buy the stuff.  They had that once but shut it down, so I don't know how successful that effort would be, but it would be more productive than asking for more freebies.