# Getting the SO sticker for the meetup group

Tags: discussion, stickers

We run Azure group in Charlotte, NC and want to distribute the SO sticker to our members.

https://www.meetup.com/Charlotte-Microsoft-Azure/members/

http://cltazure.azurewebsites.net/

Unfortunately, we don't have a letterhead as noted below. Can we still get it?

https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/09/09/how-to-get-stack-overflow-stickers/

*“If you run a user group or company meeting and you would like a batch of stickers to provide at your next meeting, please send a short letter on company/group letterhead requesting stickers to the above address. Also indicate how many you’re requesting.”*

Comment: I'll bet you could fake a letterhead in MS-Word... Just sayin'...

Comment: Actually in this day and age, that's exactly how people do *real* letterheads too ;p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described here: [May we have some more SO stickers, please?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200409/may-we-have-some-more-so-stickers-please)

We may be able to help if you get in touch via email. No guarantees, but if we have 'em and have enough time to send 'em we'll do our best.

Send details on the number of attendees along with a mailing address via the /contact form linked to at the bottom of every page.

Failing that, you can always send a big stack of [SASE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-addressed_stamped_envelope).

Comment: Thanks @Shog9. I just sent the details using the /Contact form ("Other" option).