# Is there anything like Stack Exchange Anonymous?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, stack-exchange, fun

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I keep from getting addicted to Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4004/how-can-i-keep-from-getting-addicted-to-stack-overflow)

I think I find myself addicted to Stack Overflow. Is there any organization I can join to help me out?

:-)

Comment: If you want to talk aout it: http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193/stack-exchange-anonymous

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes!** An organization already exists. It even has a very active website where addicts discuss coping strategies: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 5):

Consider yourself not too bad, you haven't earn the Enthusiast badge yet. There have been suggestion to make an "Uber-Fanatic" badge for people that login everyday for 365 days.

[Please add an "Über-Fanatic" badge!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58404/please-add-an-uber-fanatic-badge)
[Über-fanatic badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52436/uber-fanatic-badge)

And here's a user that have visited Stack Overflow for [424 consecutive days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58404/please-add-an-uber-fanatic-badge/58415#58415).

Comment: I know that I'm not competition for some folks...this is more of tongue in cheek type question.

Answer (score 0):

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=addicted

Looks like someone created a room just for you!

http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193/stack-exchange-anonymous

Comment: It's not really anonymous if your name appears when you chat, is it?