# Proposal: Free day in the visit log to account for the Oct 9th downtime

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges, activity-badges

Given the [downtime for today](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67088/135201) (Oct 9th, 2010) due to the UPS Failure, I propose giving every user that visited on **Oct 8th, 2010** a free entry in the visit log (or whatever the name may be) for **Oct 9th, 2010**.

It shouldn't matter to other users (at least not for reasons I can think of, correct me if I'm lapsing here), but having your streak broken by a datacenter issue would be a bit unfair to others going for the badge in a time period without an outage.

For those unaware this is for the [Enthusiast](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/39/enthusiast) and [Fanatic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/53/fanatic) badges, which are for consecutively visiting the site for 30 and 100 days, respectively.

Comment: Good point and this would be a fair solution. +1

Comment: Surely badges should be earned by chance and not users working to get them?

Comment: Yeah, please extend our subscription... er wait a second.

Comment: Lost 52 day consecutive streak on wordpress.stackexchange.com +1 for free day.

Comment: How could one little package from UPS cause this much trouble? I guess everyone just assumes they use FedEx.

Comment: I got pwned by this outage and it still hasn't gotten back to me!

Comment: See my comment on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52436/uber-fanatic-badge

Comment: @Daniel: You're refering to my answer wheras I meant to point to my comment on the original post in which I predicted that contributors will complain as soon as an outage occurs.

Comment: @Filburt - There's an alternative way to solve that problem, think creatively ;)

Comment: definitely. i'm striving for those badges :)

Comment: I actually missed Oct. 10th because of the downtime; how did I manage that?

Comment: I understand your plight

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is now complete, there were 2 changes that went out today:

1. If you visited on October 8th, we gave you credit for the 9th (the day we were down)
2. We re-ran badges to assign them to people who missed them *because of* missing a day on the 9th (or any other not-awarded reason, though there were only a very strange few cases badges were missing for some *other* reason).

This resulted in the following on Stack Overflow:

- 70 [Enthusiast badges](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/71/enthusiast)
- 9 [Fanatic badges](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/83/fanatic)

This was run for *all* Stack Exchange sites, any that existed during the outage got the same love (others simply wouldn't have had any entries for Oct 8th...)

Comment: I've just noticed a gap showed up in my own record for 5/13/2012. I definitely visited that day, as I got my Ethusiast badge a couple weeks ago and have been working on my Fanatic badge. Here's my profile: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1231943/davek804 is there anything I can do?

Comment: @Davek804 - your only traffic that day was a `2012-05-13 15:13:14.853` hit to the SO homepage [which has never counted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66482/consecutive-days-problem-97/66485#66485).  The login and homepages have always been explicitly excluded from the counter since you're not actually *using* the site.

Answer (score 25):

Great idea Nick. I am annoyed about this as I was on 98 consecutive days. Now I have just one.

I have visited SO every day for 3 months, answering hundreds of questions, about a third of them marked as correct. I have helped a lot of people with their problems, and now I feel let down.

We all work in IT and we understand that these things happen from time to time. But they have to be fixed when they do.

Comment: Pssst: http://stackoverflow.com/users/230428/daniel-dyson someone just got a fanatic badge ;)

Answer (score 3):

As of 12 minutes ago I received my "Fanatic" badge and the "gap" in my consecutive days has gone, so it looks like this is now resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe someone should implement this. I wonder who that person would be? :)

Comment: More than 100 days have passed since October 10th, so the point may be moot. :)