# Consecutive Days bug/glitch

Tags: support, consecutive-days, outage

Up until a few hours ago (at least I presume that's the case!), I had somewhere around the mid to late 90s in "consecutive days" showing, but as of just now Stackoverflow is showing:

[image]

Is this a (temporary, hopefully!!) side-effect of the outage earlier, or has something gone really quite horribly wrong? Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Mine is fine.  Day switched over 30 minutes ago.  Did you have activity in the 24 hours prior to those 30 minutes?

Comment: I *think* that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849853/why-bother-with-initializers-net classes as within that time period, that said I distinctly remember pootling around on SOF yesterday (Saturday GMT)

Comment: Your [activity](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7872?tab=activity) on SO shows items from the 8th UTC, but nothing from the 9th.  You posted here on the 10th UTC.  Did you view SO between there?

Comment: I can confirm that this glitch is real. I also got reset. I had around 10 consecutive days when I visited yesterday after the downtime yesterday and 1 consecutive when I logged in again now (less than 24 hours later). (Sorry my username on Stackoverflow is dsclementsen, but using the same openid on meta didn't give me the same username)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The team appear to have resolved this as I received the "Fanatic" badge 12 minutes ago on so.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to yesterday's [SO Outage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67114/stack-overflow-outage) which required the database to be restored, rebuilt and merged. I am assuming that this would have reset the consecutive days on some accounts.

Comment: Is there anything going to be "done" regarding this, do you know? For someone who had only a few days left to go to achieve their "Fanatic" badge it's a bit of a kicker :-(

Comment: @Rob I have no idea, and I am also not sure if anything can be done.

Comment: can I assume that this consecutive days count is generated from a login/activity log that hasn't been completely lost. If so, then a solution would be to give all users who had some activity on the last day of the backup a fake activity for each day that was lost. I'm disappointed to loose my 10 days, can't imagine rob's annoyance of loosing his run so close to the fanatic badge.

Comment: Nick Craver has a good suggestion to add a day for each person who had a day counted the day before the outage. This would help me, because I was on 98 days. Bad timing! :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67109/proposal-free-day-in-the-visit-log-to-account-for-the-oct-9th-downtime