# Consecutive days reset across all of Stack Exchange

Tags: support, badges, consecutive-days, activity-badges

This question ( [Consecutive Days bug/glitch](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67161/consecutive-days-bug-glitch) ) is exactly the same problem I've had. I logged on yesterday and I have a screenshot to prove that I DID in fact, have activity yesterday. But today all my SE accounts (I have been clocking up a few at the same time - Stack Overflow, Code Review, Christianity, etc.) have been reset, and I was on 50+ days for some of them.

I have two questions:

1. Was there an outage as described in Rob's question yesterday? I logged in around 10:00 AM as I do everyday (South African time is UTC + 2 hours), so this isn't a case of me hopping between time zones.
2. How do I fix this for all 7 of my stack exchange accounts?

Comment: My streak is fine

Comment: Did you view pages **other** than the home page? You have to do more than just "log in".

Comment: I just logged in but that has been working for the last 50 days (I spend more time on one or two of the 7 accounts, but I'm mainly focusing on getting those consecutive days up for the fanatics badge :-)

Comment: Also, across all accounts, it showed 50 or so consecutive days, last seen yesterday (that's the screenshot I have). On refreshing, it updated to 1 consecutive day, last seen x seconds ago.

Comment: This has just happened to me for 5/12/2012 (on SO). Same deal, I visited and looked around as I do. I was at about 53 days. Any solution?

Comment: Also getting this problem now. Every three or four days it resets. I have an app tab so it is open every single day for hours, and it's still resetting every few days.