# Consecutive days missed

Tags: support, stack-overflow, consecutive-days

I visited Stack Overflow for about 82 days in a row (starting January 21st), including yesterday (April 13th) and today (April 14th).

All times UTC of course (I thought that was clear but I've now added it to my question as a relevant info).

All visits are in a logged-in session of course.

I've just discovered that SO didn't "see" the April 13th visit, so my consecutive days visits were zeroed !!

**It's a bug for sure.** I have open tabs which my browser's history shows that are from April 13th. More than 20 of them.
I saw this one: [Consecutive Days bug/glitch](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67161/consecutive-days-bug-glitch) , and it's clearly what happened to me. Please help! I'm so close to getting the Fanatic badge...

Comment: You sure that you visited on April 13th, __UTC__, and not just in your local timezone?

Comment: What time does your history show?

Comment: If you open your profile and click on the consecutive days count, a fancy window will pop up to let you know which days the site thinks you visited it on; not much you can do with that information, though.

Comment: I'm sure I visited in April 13th, UTC.

Comment: @Jeff - it's a bug. Not a glitch on my side.

Comment: It's likely neither, Ofer, but rather a misapprehension about what "visit" means in this context.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Consecutive days problem #97?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66482/consecutive-days-problem-97)

Comment: I've seen hundreds of these and they *all* resolve the same -- the user provably by our logs did not visit an interior page in the UTC time. But if you absolutely must insist, email the address at the bottom of every web page we serve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been bitten by this before, too. The personal page didn't seem to count. You have to visit the question overview, afaik, maybe single questions.

Comment: I will reward you the "accept" since your answer was the closest. yhw42's answer was irrelevant to my case since I commented and updated  my question to say I'm working in UTC, but he didn't update his answer. He also didn't give references to his last claim. So for the sake of these thread's future readers, here is the answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66485/167417

Comment: What kind of answer is this?

Answer (score 8):

I'm not convinced it's as clear as that.

Do you have time logs for when you were active on the site? What are those times when you translate it into the UTC time zone?

As stated in the answers [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/55394), SO days are measured in the UTC time zone, and you must visit in each 24 hour UTC day to keep your Consecutive Days counter counting.

Also, in order to count as a visit, you must do more than just open the main page.

Comment: I visited more than 20 times in April 13th, UTC time. I'm 1,000,000% sure of that.

Comment: As for your last sentence: "in order to count as a visit, you must do more than just open the main page." - please define "more".

Comment: I believe it's kept somewhat vague, @Ofer, to counter gaming.

Comment: @OferZelig: I think the exact conditions are secret, or at least I haven't seen them anywhere. Browsing through a few pages on the site should be enough, though. I'm pretty sure you don't have to post anything.

Comment: @hammar Just visiting your user page counts as a visit.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta, still - they should note that "hitting one page doesn't count" so I'll know I must do more, and they can still keep the specific details on how they "see" a visit vague, to fight gaming as you say.