# Why did my Consecutive Days reset?

Tags: bug, consecutive-days

I had like 303 or so consecutive days in Physics.SE but they reset. To my best knowledge I visited everyday so is there a limit/bug?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129278/245360