# Lost consecutive days status

Tags: bug, status-completed, consecutive-days

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proposal: Free day in the visit log to account for the Oct 9th downtime](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67109/proposal-free-day-in-the-visit-log-to-account-for-the-oct-9th-downtime)

Due to the server outage yesterday, my consecutive days status has been reset from 98 days to 1, even though I visited StackOverflow in the morning yesterday. How do I get this status restored?

Comment: Duplicate http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67109/proposal-free-day-in-the-visit-log-to-account-for-the-oct-9th-downtime

Comment: Is this really a duplicate? The linked question is about users that didn't visit the site that day because it was down when they tried. This question seems to be about users who did visit, but it wasn't counted (presumably because of data loss from the crash).

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, mainly because the other question hasn't been answered yet! If there was an accepted answer on the other question then I wouldn't have to ask it again would I? I'm going to ask it again until I get an answer.

Comment: Are you trying to get banned?

Comment: I don't understand why people are being so vitriolic about this. Surely I am the one with a grievance here. I am really bloody angry about this. I have spent many many hours of my time helping people on Stack Overflow. Then they mess up and I miss out on a badge. Then I get threatened with being banned. Go ahead and ban me. I won't be helping any of your users out again. You risk losing one of your top 1% of users by reputation over something silly.

Comment: Good grief, Daniel! It's a little gold circle. Have some perspective. And give Jeff and crew a day to look at matters.

Comment: Fair comment, Michael. In fact, I'm the guy that marked it as a great comment. It's just, you don't know the grief I get from my wife for the amount of time I spend on SO. I didn't really get pissed about the outage and the loss of data. It was more about the closure of the question. Rather than close it, just answer it. A simple "We are looking into this" from one of the moderators would be enough.

Comment: And don't undeestimate the importance of the little gold circles. Some people (mostly ex boy scouts) consider them to be really important for recognition.

Comment: I hope you've cooled down a bit so I will just make a note about duplication. Having multiple questions asking for the same set of answers doesn't truly resolve anything faster or better. That's why if they're asking for the same thing but neither has an answer, closing as a duplicate is a useful route. It's not because we're trying to shut you out; rather, this way it points you to what question to look at for updates on the situation. If there's no answer to that one, you're no more likely to get an answer here if this were open.

Comment: Thanks Grace. Indeed, I am feeling cooler.