# Consecutive Days Lost During Data Center Migration

Tags: support, consecutive-days

After the data center migration this weekend, my consecutive days went down from about 57-58 to 0. Yes, I know that SO consecutive days is on UTC (for me this resets at 8:00PM each night since I'm EST). But I was logged onto SO on Saturday (the day I was reset) as well as the day before and the day after well within the normal cut off.

Has any one else seen this happen to them? I've seen several other people asking similar questions on Meta including [this proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67109/152726) after the Oct. 9 downtime. I do not believe this is a duplicate question though because I'm seeing this after the data center migration.

Also, is there a way to view activity time in the odata.stackexchange.com site?

Comment: My counter is at 45 for MSO and 9 for SO.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68345/proposal-free-day-in-the-visit-log-to-account-for-the-oct-23rd-downtime -- any daily activity is logged, so you should *disregard* the display of consecutive days until this issue is resolved (for obvious reasons, it's low priority).