# Can a Reddit-like SOPA-blackout be of benefit to SO and/or its users?

Tags: discussion, sopa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any chance of StackExchange blacking out Jan 18, along with Reddit, in opposition of SOPA/PIPA?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118612/any-chance-of-stackexchange-blacking-out-jan-18-along-with-reddit-in-oppositio)

Reddit will go down in protest to SOPA, a law that could, in theory, bring down SOFU, Reddit, and whatnot (probably some sites you like will go down, but I think not sites like Facebook or Twitter, solely for their popularity).

You probably know about all of that already.

This question is not "please bring down SO". Of course I love SO and I'd be a little annoyed if it goes down for a few hours or a day. Some people (IMO everyone against the idea of such a protest) wouldn't get any work done while SO is down.

Now, that makes me think it's a wonderful opportunity to make the people that depend on SO to get work done to:

- Realize that they're being lazy some/most of the time (*some* users are like that)
- Being forced to think for themselves for these few hours, potentially making them better users
- See what SOPA would be like

and for SO it's an opportunity to:

- Make its users see the value the site has for them
- Since it will probably be tweeted g+ed and facebooked, it will draw attention to both SO and to SOPA (even for non-SO users!)
- Show how much the site cares about doing something significant (I'd see SO in a completely different light after such a thing)
- Save some bandwidth ;)

...All of that in the account of SOPA, but it could be good for more than just warning its user base about the to-be Great Firewall of America.

And I know [some people don't care](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114020/please-do-not-use-stack-overflow-to-promote-social-causes). Some also won't care about global warming until there's any effect on their lives, others didn't care about hitler assuming power until he did, etc. There's a lot of short-sighted people, and those are the ones that will benefit the most from seeing *SOPA does apply to them too and it's real*

So, before this question gets closed as not constructive: it's about wether SOPA is presenting an opportunity (an excuse) to blackout the site *for it's own profit* (and of its users).

Comment: This question is NOT an exact duplicate. It was closed just because it annoyed moderators. Guess what, SOPA is not in my country and I care more than you.

Comment: Could I see a link to the duplicate? I want to read what everyone said

Comment: @GabrielFair There's no duplicate.

Comment: @GabrielFair http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118612/176881

Comment: @simplesekret that question is about asking if SO will be blacking along with reddit. My question is if such a thing would have beneficial effects outside of SOPA. I could well have left reddit and SOPA out of all I said and the question would remain.

Comment: I know the question is big, but it feels bad that some people did not read it. I don't know if I'm supposed to post shorter questions or what.

Comment: Well, I don't see the point in making a distinction between "Would blacking out the site be of benefit" and "Will the site be blacked out". I think that's the general sense of those voting this as "Exact duplicate".