# Should "Title Says It All" questions be edited or closed?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, asking-questions

I see many questions with really long titles and bodies with nothing more than:

> "Title says it all"
>   "See title. ~thanks~"
>   "In PHP. thanks!"

Examples (a couple I already edited):

- [How can I know the body content is outputted (then cannot use the header function)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2937739/918414)
- [If there is a button in a link, when I click this button, how to avoid the link?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4335464/918414)
- [ASP.NET: Could anyone provide some C# paging codes in Repeater or ListView controls for me to learn](https://stackoverflow.com/q/420699/918414)

I assume the "thanks" variants at the end are to get around a minimum length. Should these be edited or voted to close? If edited, how? Should I just repeat the title in the body?

It seems like a question that can fit entirely in the title is inherently low quality.

UPDATE: There's over 700 of just the "title says it all" pattern for anyone that wants to have fun editing these: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Title+says+it+all%22

Comment: I was about to say that I was shocked that these questions were let through the minimum quality filter.  Then I looked at their dates.

Comment: I don't see why "close" is a response to *this* problem at all. If the question itself is bad, close it, but if the question is fine they just didn't state it right, state it right for them and ask for more details.

Comment: @BenBrocka To be fair, most of what he's referring to are *old* questions, so asking the OP isn't usually a productive course of action if they aren't active on the site still (and there are a number of them out there like this).  That said, at times when the OP is not going to respond, it falls on us (the community) to figure out what to do with this.  I agree though that close is not necessarily the right response to this problem in *every case*, as always, *it depends* (I'm sure you've seen my answer below elaborating).

Comment: The examples are old but whatever we decide would (presumably) be the policy going forward. Closing questions is scary for new users so I personally prefer to avoid a "close first and edit later" attitude unless there is a good reason answers shouldn't be allowed on a question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have to respectfully disagree with [Andrew's response](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119411/140951) that it is not a question.  While I don't necessarily *like* questions that are completely self-described in the title, there are many questions which really don't *need* anything beyond the title to explain what's desired in the question.

Here is an example that I think is cut-and-dry (in the interest of transparency, had a "very low quality" flag on it which I declined, with a custom message indicating that it was very difficult for me to decline as it was "cut-and-dry, asked-and-answered" after looking at it for a long while):

[Excel: Assign a macro to a hyperlink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465017/excel-assign-a-macro-to-a-hyperlink)

In the above, there is a clear [answer that is accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465017/excel-assign-a-macro-to-a-hyperlink).

Looking at the descriptive text of the close as "not a real question" reason, it states:

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. See the FAQ.

In the question above, it is none of those things.

While [pithy is antithetical to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118612/any-chance-of-stack-exchange-blacking-out-jan-18-along-with-reddit-and-wikipedi/118614#comment311838_118614), there's currently not a close reason for it.

Yes, lack of content is usually a red flag indicating that a question *may be* very low quality, but it's not an immediate condemnation of whether or not it is low quality.

Note that Jeff has commented that the criteria for VLQ is that the post is *not salvageable*.  In the case above, there's nothing to salvage.  It's just...  *brief*.

So the overall recommendation is, *it depends*.  Some recommendations:

- Try to *edit* the post to provide better content (thank you to [GraceNote for pointing that out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119476/140951)).  An example would be the [edit I performed on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/841158/revisions).  It doesn't put words in the OPs mouth, it doesn't detract from the answers provided, and indicates *something* to help expand the question in general.
- If it has an accepted answer, it likely means that *someone* interpreted it correctly in the eyes of the user, and it really needs a little love to give it some more content (unless it has *other* glaring issues which it should be closed for).
- If there are multiple answers with upvotes, it's an indication that multiple people understood the question as asked (brief as it is) well enough to provide answers, and that *others* on top of that indicated that they understood the question *and* answers enough to provide an upvote on it.
- If the question is upvoted, it's *possible* that people understand the question, but as we all know, voting is not anywhere near a reliable indicator of whether or not a question is good (I'd look at this as a *last* resort and *only* if you have nothing else to rely on, and even then, take it with a grain of salt).  Note this applies to answers as well, but in the point above, it's the presence of *multiple upvoted answers* (which is different from a *single upvoted question*) that is the indicator.
- If there's a duplicate of it on the site (and in a lot of cases, there probably are), vote to close it as a duplicate and then flag for moderator attention, indicating it's a duplicate. This is much better for the site overall, since we *like* multiple representations of asking the same thing (it boosts organic search).

In the event that the question meets none of the above criteria, I'd advise the following (assuming one has the privileges to do so):

- If the question is recent, vote to close and possibly leave a comment on what exactly makes it VLQ.  This has the dual effect of a) letting others know why the question is VLQ, as well as let's the poster know that there are problems and they might be able to edit it to provide better content.
- If the question is *not* recent, then vote to close/delete and flag for moderator attention *with a custom message. Indicate *why* the question is not clear or deserves to be close in the case that a title might be interpreted as cut-and-dry.  This will help moderators tremendously in understanding your point of view on why it's VLQ and help us make the best decision for the site.

Comment: -1, if they can't be bothered to write something of substance in the question body then I can't be bothered to leave their question open.

Comment: @sixlettervariables As indicated in my fourth bullet point.  It says it *very* clearly that upvotes on a question are no where *near* an interpretation that a question is a *good* question, and this should only be used as a last resort and taken with an *extreme* grain of salt.

Comment: My approach is if it was worth asking once, it'll get asked again.

Comment: @sixlettervariables Suggested advice in the *fifth* bullet point.  Always better to try and close as a dupe if it exists as *we like dupes* because it improves organic search (and we can always cull them out later if a dupe does the job of providing quality content for us). =)

Comment: I actually don't disagree with what you say here at all. I posted my answer from mobile and so didn't flesh out everything. However, I was careful to say "*I think many of those*". I agree it's absolutely *possible* to have a real question of such simplicity.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I didn't downvote out of hostility, honest. =)  While I agree with the statement that *those* instances can be deleted, my concern is that it wo be taken as the canonical statement for *all* questions of that type (and we know that's what people will do) and based my dissent on that.  I assume you'll flesh it out at which point I'll review my vote. =)

Answer (score 22):

My recommendation is that if you run into a question where the body is just "See the title" or similar, **revise the question body to rephrase the presented question**. [Like casperOne](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119471/140951), I don't believe that the style alone is enough to warrant closure - if the underlying question is close-worthy, or if the lack of detail is enough to make it unanswerable, that's closeworthy. But if it's a valid question in its brevity, then closing isn't very wise to do.

There are two advantages to rephrasing the question in the body. The first is that this makes it look better - just pointing at the title looks bad. The second is that **having a second wording improves the searchability of the question**. Remember how many problems we have with duplicates because people just phrased things differently? By using two ways to phrase the same problem (when possible), it creates two avenues of access within a single question. As our goal is to help people to find these questions in addition to having the answers, improving searchability is a great way to handle questions which otherwise are just the title.

To take a specific point out of your question, if the title is unwieldy and long to allow for this, another course of action is to **condense the title and bring the complexity into the question body**. This isn't always feasible, and often requires talking with the author to set it up properly, but in the end, the meat of the information should be in the question body, not in the title.

Comment: Word use nitpick: the primary meaning of verbiage refers to the superfluous use of language, which is probably not what you meant.

Comment: @jwiscarson I'm more familiar with its usage to just mean word choice (though this apparently is a predominantly US usage). I imagine the primary meaning you're referring to draws a common root with verbosity, though, neh?

Comment: Yes -- I say this out owing to my background in technical writing. My professors absolutely hated seeing verbiage used in a non-pejorative sense. Colloquially, you used verbiage correctly, and the colloquial use may eventually overtake the technical use. Feel free to disregard my pedantry. :)

Comment: What about triviality? Isn't a question that can fit in a title, sometimes not even a long one, too trivial?

Comment: @ThinkingStiff Triviality an issue that is independent of the question being in the title. It's like how if two questions have the same answer, they *might* be duplicates, or they might just be two completely different problems with the solution being the same. A tiny question is an *indicator* that it might be a low quality question, but it is only that - an indicator. It's the kind of thing that may promote asking for more information, closing if it is far too vague, or it may just be sufficient without being trivial.

Comment: @ThinkingStiff It's quite possible to do very difficult questions in few words, but it doesn't make it right to do so in the title. Picking good titles is an art; ask any newspaper subeditor.

Comment: I think of it more like the bread 'filling' in a sandwich, like a Big Mac. The nutritional value it adds is superficial, but the appearance of value is greatly increased. If you can make a minor edit that takes the question out of 'lazy' and more into 'quite succinct', it's really worth the effort. I agree that it helps yield better results in searches, but the real benefit is not seeing extremely terse but useful questions voted to the bottom of the results.

Answer (score 9):

I think many of those can be closed as not a real question. You could leave a comment to ask for more information when the asker is still active.

---

When I say "many of those", I'm making a wild (though educated) guess as to the ratio of good/bad questions that follow this pattern. My guess is that many of the questions which can possibly fit entirely in the title of a question would qualify as "not a real question" because they won't be detailed enough to be answerable.

That is, that it qualifies that "*it's hard to tell what is being asked here*", to paraphrase the close reason.

I should have been more careful, though, to state that it is not merely the fact that the question fits entirely in the subject which causes this. It is certainly *possible* to craft an appropriate question in such a short length. It's just hard to do.

In some of the cases, you could leave a comment to request that the asker flesh out their question with more details. You might do so with or without also issuing a vote to close as I noted above. I don't think the judgment there is any different than any normal question which might apply as "not a real question".

---

Another item I realize I could have been more detailed about: If I was not at 3K reputation on the site, I would probably not *flag* most of these questions as not a real question, as that is demanding that a moderator make an up-or-down decision on the spot. I would instead leave a comment (if the user is still active), and only flag it if it's really, very clear that it is "not a real question" in any way, shape or form.

Being a 3K user on Stack Overflow, though, I would *vote* to close as NARQ. In fact, I did so on each of the three you posted. I feel the 'vote to close' option is a bit less strong, because it requires 5 votes to close, so others must agree with me.

I think I see that you flagged a number of these questions as NARQ, and perhaps you did so in response to my initial answer. If that's the case, I deserve the down votes I got on this! I deserve them anyway for leaving this answer so simple for so long... bad me! (FYI: I truly don't mind DV's like these, anyway.)

Comment: I did take your advice and went and voted to close/flagged quite a few. But I agree with you. I think most of these questions are really low quality and not very useful. The consensus, though, seems to be to give the questions more of a chance. Since casperOne and GraceNote's answers I've been copying the title into the body more and just voting to close on really bad ones.

Answer (score 4):

"Title Says It All", while definitely annoying is merely bad posting style. You can't take it at face value and say "questions that can fit in the title should be closed" (although this may frequently be true). These should be edited, if for no other reason, to set a better example to other users, even if they do get closed.

It doesn't take much effort to:

1. Copy the title
2. Put it in the question body
3. Do what you can to make both items more substantial or clearer

If after this, the question is still unfit, then yes - vote to close.

Comment: I did a search on "title says it all" http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Title+says+it+all%22 and like the "how to find answers that are not answers" search terms, this sure takes you to the rude part of SO (which I do not normally see.) It's like a "leading indicator" or something, there's a good chance the OP and askers alike don't really "get" the SO paradigm. I edit where I can, but **"… the title says it all... now answer!"** is probably not salvagable.

Comment: This is perhaps how I should have worded my answer at first. I am just a tiny bit more pessimistic about the usefulness of editing such questions.

Comment: I guess the older posts are worse, the new versions usually have a little extra to bypass the min char/quality filters. Something like "The title says it all. Is there anyway this can be done? Thanks in advance.". Actually those seem equally bad.