# Why are question marks not mandatory in titles?

Tags: discussion, questions, title

Quora mandates question marks at the end of titles. Why doesn't Stack Exchange?

Comment: Unnecessary clutter which is irrelevant to the actual point?

Comment: I believe on "Jeopardy", this is relevant, SO....  *Not so much*

Comment: Related... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115327/stop-rewriting-trailing-exclamation-marks-as-question-marks

Comment: @casperOne: That would be a _really_ fun SO spoof site.  Askers make statements as "questions" and answerers add questions which would result in those statements as "answers."  Too bad Area 51 doesn't generally like spoof sites :(

Comment: @David There are technologies out there that help you create your own....

Comment: @casperOne: I may have to resort to that.  It would be way more fun/featureful/popular on SE 2.0, though.

Comment: Oh, how I love getting down-votted to hell for asking a question. Not a feature request, a question. Gotta love Meta.

Comment: @David: StackExchange hates fun.

Comment: @ripper234: Down-votes mean we disagree with you, is all.

Comment: This is because titles aren't supposed to be questions.  They're supposed to summarize the question in the body.

Comment: @Rocket - yeah yeah, I know what down-votes mean on Meta. I don't like that. Also, my question does not contain any opinion of mine, so you can't disagree with me.

Comment: I'm going to lose all my Meta rep on this question.

Comment: Your post also contains no meat

Comment: @random - is this a Meta Meme I missed?

Comment: It's low quality and fits entirely in a tweet. You may think all downvotes on Meta are about disagreement, but that doesn't mean you can skip any effort

Comment: @random - I don't know about that ... I thought the question is a good one, but the hivemind obviously disagrees. I don't tweet questions, I come to Stack Exchange to ask them. How would you elaborate on it to improve it?

Comment: Well, you could explain why you think titles _should_ be mandatory. Otherwise, nothing separates this question from "Why are exclamation points not mandatory in titles?" "Why don't all questions have to contain the word 'fizzbar'?" "Why don't you have to wait for an even-numbered hour in your local time zone to post answers?" and the like.

Comment: @PopularDemand - because AFAIK, in proper English, questions end in a question mark ... it's that simple.

Comment: Why is this question nominated for deletion?

Comment: @ripper234 I was replying to the question you asked random, "How would you elaborate on it to improve it?" My point -- and, I believe, random's -- was that you need to give your questions more substance, like background info on why a topic matters or why you believe a certain behavior is good or bad. In this specific case, you're making an assumption that all titles are questions, and I think a lot of people would disagree.

Answer (score 12):

Looks like a silly check to add.

Titles do not have to ask a question - they are there to give a brief summary of the issue.

The question body should contain the actual question.

As for citing Quora practices - Stack Exchange is not Quora and there is no reason for it to mimic/copy/slavishly follow Quora practices.

Comment: I'm citing it just as an example worth considering, not as something we have to copy.

Answer (score 4):

The question title should just give an idea of the question's topic; the fact is actually written as question is just a matter of style.

For example, I could use one of the following titles, and there would not be any difference about the topic being reported.

- How do I change the string used by a third-party module in Drupal 7?
- Changing string used from a module in Drupal 7
- Altering the string used from a module, when using Drupal 7

If the question's title doesn't have a question mark at the end, that doesn't mean the question is not really a question. If Stack Exchange were sites where a user can write a blog post to suggest how to do something, or a question, then it would be probably necessary to distinguish between what is a suggestion, and what is a question. This is not what happens in Stack Exchange sites, which follow a Q&A format.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see why they should be.

The more restrictions we put on user input, the more users are going to have to change their content to fit those restrictions.  Changing that content to fit an automated mechanism all too often means reducing the quality of that content.

In many cases, the question is more complex than can be worded in a short title.  The title is just that, a title.  It's not the question.

We also don't want to encourage situations where the body is nothing more than:

> See title for question

where the title is actually longer than the body.

Comment: [We already have that situation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/119410/140951)

Comment: @David:  Actually, there are some restrictions: for example, exclamation points are forbidden at the end of titles (but not elsewhere in the title).  Though that could be seen as beneficial, to keep questions from acting like shouting.

Comment: @PeterO.: True.  _Some_ restrictions are in place.  And I imagine their effects on the content have been thought out and scrutinized.  So I guess a more accurate extension to my point would be, "I don't see how this additional restriction would do more good than harm."