# what is that unicoins all about? Is it a playground for boys with keyboard?

Tags: discussion, unicoins

It is really worrying, cause I had a an opinion of stackoverflow as of respectable, knowledge driven source...

Or maybe it is heading in direction of social networking and becoming another social media tycoon?

Your thoughts?

Comment: Check this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122026/what-is-unicorn-on-stack-overflow and this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227363/what-are-stack-overflow-unicoins

Comment: "*Is it a playground for boys with keyboard?*" What?

Comment: First of all it that silly logo appeared on my page only today.

Secondly the use of "Is it a playground for boys with keyboard?" is figurative. In my opinion mining coins by hitting the rock really makes you a 'rock in your brain'.

Moreover I am quite concerned that they want to commercialize it.

If they need support they could just ask, like wikipedia does and I am sure there would be plenty of people willing to donate some funds.

That is an open discussion, not the place where you show off that you are right.

Comment: @d689p Hey, don't worry, it's just for April Fools' Day. Tomorrow all the unicorns and unicoins will disappear.

Comment: @Adinia the April Fool Day will pass, but some fools will stay fools :-)

Comment: Gain a sense of humor, please. Your killjoy nonsense has put me in a bad mood for the rest of the day.

Answer (score 19):

I actually went to Unicoin Summit 2014 and they explained that unicoins should make the site *more* respectable and knowledge-driven.

Apparently, the effect is still kicking in.

Answer (score 15):

Stack Exchange Inc. wishes to emphasize that we absolutely do not discriminate by gender, and that if there were a playground, people of any gender and/or sexual identity would be welcome to participate.

Comment: By "any", do you mean to include "no"?

Comment: Ok, this is a good point.

But what about other people choice? Who are not willing to see the the logo with emphasize on that subject? Why it should shout into my face. It is either a direct marketing or propaganda.

Why they are not showing pics or logos of happy families, well being for everybody, good mood, motivation speeches for programmers and people who dedicate themselves for improving the life through progress and new knowledge. But not something extravagant to taste.

If you are bored, go for walk or meet up with your friends or girlfriend.

Comment: @d689p if you don't like unicorns, just click "buy powers", then choose the "No sidebar widget" option. You can do that with just 20 of the 75 free unicoins. No more unicorns. We do allow people to opt out of happiness. Also, give it a day... it might grow on you...

Comment: @MarcGravell if you call this happiness then I can see a unicorn right now :-) (and it's not directed towards you, I mean it is an illusion)