# Who is behind the unicorn-pony mystery?

Tags: discussion, voting, unicoins, unicorns

Who will benefit from it and how to treat this anomaly?

Please objective answers only!

Answer (score 4):

Objectivly spoken, young unicorns are ponies too. We should clearly stop this ageism.

Comment: Nope. Young unicorns are called "filly". I prescrive a dose of My Little Ponies: Friendship is Magic to avoid further misunderstandings :P

Comment: A unicorn is a weaponized pony. A unicorn who is not old enough to carry a weapon should be reported to the police.... or flagged for moderator attention.

Comment: @S.L.Barth +10 if I could (weaponized pony LOL)

Comment: @SPArchaeologist I'm very sorry and will do as you recommended.

Comment: **No. Ponies are fully grown horses below a certain height threshold. Baby horses are foals. Got it?** (I'm sorry, it's one of my pet peeves.)

Comment: @michaelb958 I know. Unsually I would naturally side with you, but not today ;) Also, HERETIC!

Comment: @DaImTo Thank you, but I cannot claim credit for that highly scientific observation. See [The Many Memes of Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/122028/168333).

Answer (score 4):

Actually good chance the mastermind behind this is no other than [Pëkka](//meta.stackexchange.com/users/138112/pekka) who came up with the idea of [Unicorn Dollars](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/213830/152859):

[image]

The way from bills to coins is short so I'll take a guess this was the seed of Unicoins. :D