# Why do unicorn-related posts have so many upvotes?

Tags: discussion, up-votes, unicorns

Why are there so many upvotes and reputation for any unicorn-related post?
I just cannot understand it.

Comment: Because unicorns are the symbol of joy and innocence. Plus, **they're pink**.

Comment: +1 This question is about unicorns

Comment: They're a meme: See [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19479/168333) on The Many Memes of Meta.

Comment: Posts about unicorns have more readers

Comment: [Not](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228018/152859) [any](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227964/152859) [question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227681/152859).

Comment: Why does a question asking about upvotes on unicorn-related posts has so many upvotes? ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I am so tempted to edit this question to say "tend to have so many..."  ;)

Comment: @shadowWizard I helped close #2- that one was downright shameful :(

Comment: @BlueIce nah, I think it was innocent attempt to have fun.

Answer (score 7):

Unicorns where among the founders of this site. Without them there would be a different site, probably one using an hyphen. But luckily they where at the right time and place and made a difference.

So posts on unicorns honour them and by upvoting them, you sacrifice some of your daily voting capability in mere glory of the unicorn.

It's either that, or that unicorns are a meme used often so it strengthens the community bond. Just like free hand circles, but they are less cute.

Answer (score 6):

Just look at its majesty!

[image]

[attribution](http://unicornify.appspot.com/)

Answer (score 5):

That questions have so many upvotes because so many people have clicked up-arrow while browsing them. It's a technical explanation.

Why people were so eager to click that button, it's more a psychological issue. I think they've expected some easter egg after reaching the daily vote limit (maybe up-arrow changing into unicorn horn).

Another explanation is, people were more bored yeasteday, because they didn't dare to ask their bosses what should they do next and they were out of tasks....