# Any chance of some awareness raising on behalf of Python's trademark issues?

Tags: discussion, community-bulletin, trademark, intellectual-property

> Related [Any chance of Stack Exchange blacking out Jan 18, along with Reddit and Wikipedia in opposition of SOPA/PIPA?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118612/any-chance-of-stack-exchange-blacking-out-jan-18-along-with-reddit-and-wikipedi)

Van Lindberg, chairman of the Python Software Foundation, posted a "call to arms", if you will, on the [PSF blog](http://pyfound.blogspot.ca/2013/02/python-trademark-at-risk-in-europe-we.html) about some trademark issues they're having.

> For anyone who works in a company that has an office in a EU Community
> member state, we need your help.
>
> There is a company in the UK that is trying to trademark the use of
> the term "Python" for all software, services, servers... pretty much
> anything having to do with a computer. Specifically, it is the company
> that got a hold on the python.co.uk domain 13 years ago. At that time
> we weren't looking a lot at trademark issues, and so we didn't get
> that domain.

Python is the 9<sup>th</sup> most widely used tag with 164 *thousand* questions so this is highly relevant to the Stack Overflow community, and I assume Programmers and probably some more communities.

Is Stack Exchange willing to make issues like this visible to the wider community through the Community Bulletin and can this be one of them?

#### Relevant links

- [Full blog post](http://pyfound.blogspot.ca/2013/02/python-trademark-at-risk-in-europe-we.html)
- [Article in the Guardian](http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/2013/feb/15/python-trademark-bid)
- [Opposed European Community Trademark](http://oami.europa.eu/CTMOnline/RequestManager/en_DetailCTM_NoReg#)
- [PSF's trademark application](http://oami.europa.eu/CTMOnline/RequestManager/en_DetailCTM_NoReg#)

<sub>P.S. Our letter is being written as my company has been using Python for 20 years</sub>

[image: http://www.lolcats.com/featured/20384-halp.html]

Comment: If you would like to write a blog post for the [Programmers community blog](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/), we'd certainly welcome it (and not just because we haven't posted in a while). Other than that, I'm not so sure anything should be done. Lots of worthy causes we could contribute to, but that's simply _not_ what Stack Overflow / Exchange is about.

Comment: Perhaps if this is of significant importance to the Python people, they might consider taking out an add on Stack Overflow instead? It's their cause. Let them do something about it. Note: I have absolutely no idea if SO/SE would welcome something like that (it being somewhat political and all), but let's not put up banners or have a call to arms for every issue that might in some way affect a part of our community. That might end up being a slippery slope kind of deal.

Comment: How does one go about submitting something @Yannis? It's not clear from the blog page or the chat room; I'll certainly write something. As to whether it's what SO/SE is about, that's part of the question :-). I guess your and Bart's comment answers that.

Comment: I care a great deal about this issue, but SO is not the place to try and promote it, I'd say. This is not something that is going to affect Stack Exchange itself, now, is it?

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Going into the chat room now, ping me there (and will add a section in the blog's about page on how to contribute at some point, I promise).

Comment: Perhaps if it was iPython you'd get a system banner

Comment: Closing this as "off topic" (or at all) is absurd. The question is «Is Stack Exchange willing to make issues like this visible to the wider community...» If the answer is "No.", then fine, but this most certainly _is_ about Stack Exchange, just like the [questions about obituaries](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109160/) in the system banner.  Aside to @ben: It's possible that "How can awareness of this issue be raised on SO/Programmers?" might get better results than "Can the company do something?" -- maybe not, though. Just a thought.

Comment: @JoshCaswell (and everyone else) http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/02/endangered-pythons/

Comment: Hey @Yannis! Thanks for getting that sped through, though I'm now being overly critical about my writing style and thinking of other things I should have added :-).

Answer (score 2):

I think we all agree with you, but this just isn't what stack exchange is about. Try raising awareness in chat, maybe write a post for the Programmer's blog, but just go look at what happened when we just put *one* little banner about SOPA. Things exploded. And that was something that could have utterly destroyed the Internet. Yeah.