# Is there a recognition mechanism for linking to existing Stack Overflow posts?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, hyperlinks

Well, I have imagined this to happen as follows:

I ask a question. A person answers it. In his post there is a link to an existing Stack Overflow post which deals with the same subject. I assume he must have gone through the post before and thought it was useful; hence the link.

So why can't we come out with a strategy to recognize such posts (i.e. those which are linked to in other posts)? I don't mean that we reward every such link. If the person who has asked a question marks an answer he has received, and that answer contains a link to another post on Stack Overflow, then the linked-to post should be rewarded somehow. Also, the person who has answered the question should be awarded a little extra rep, since he has referred to that post.

Comment: FWIW, I [suggested a badge](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/additional-badge-ideas/55470#55470) that would be awarded to a user if his answer was internally linked *x* times by other users.

Comment: Well, of _course_ a __person__ answers it.  We have... ways... of keeping the robotic riffraff out.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a recipe for internal link-farming...

If a link (internal or external) improves an answer, then there's already potential for reward: the answer will get more up-votes. Assuming readers *follow* the link, find the original answer useful and up-vote it, there's a reward for the original author as well.

And of course, [linking to welbog is its own reward](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19507#19507).

Comment: i don't get it. could you elaborate more...who or what is welbog?

Comment: @deostroll: it's a bit of an inside joke - don't stress about it. ;-)

Comment: @deostroll Welbog is a creature of extraordinary mysteriousness. We aren't even sure just how mysterious he is. But it's a lot. Also his [profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/52443/welbog) is legendary.

Comment: @deo: D.O N.O.T A.S.K.! He can here you. Shhhhhhhh!

Answer (score 2):

One of my favourite passtimes is to go to ServerFault questions that have been asked dozens of times and give the user a [link to](https://serverfault.com/questions/161664/) [everywhere it](https://serverfault.com/questions/126024) [has been asked](https://serverfault.com/questions/139017) before. Someone once called me the Rollerdex of Serverfault.

Am I awesome? Yes. Did I do this by going to http://www.google.com.au/search?hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=Tt5&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-GB%3Aofficial&q=site%3Aserverfault.com+favourite+vps&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai= ? Yes. Should I be rewarded for this? Unlikely.

If you just do a google search before asking your question, then people like me won't have to post thirteen links to duplicates.

Comment: in the scenario you describe shouldn't these be flagged as duplicates and closed/merged instead?

Comment: It IS awesome, and those links give less-knowledgeable users a treasure-trove of related reading material.

Comment: @Matt, a lot of them are. But when I'm the only one giving them close votes, nothing's going to happen fast.