# Badge idea for voting on old questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges, badge-request

I have a suggestion for a badge:

Generally, it's encouraged to first search for a topic before you ask a question, because there's already a lot of questions asked...
The problem with this, however, is that if you're actually some kind of 'junior developer' (whatever that means), most of the questions you can possibly ask, were already be asked by others, so it's not possible for you to get any points for that.

Yeah, I know: "If you have a question, you just want it answered, the points don't matter". I don't care, I want points, or at least: a badge. I understand, that it wouldn't work to get points for votes on old questions, since that would induce spamming of votes on old questions, and I'm pretty sure a lot of users would hit their daily cap of votes more often. So I'm thinking about a badge for that instead:

A badge for voting on questions, that are more than 3 months (or half a year or whatever) old at the time you vote on them.  You've found them by searching and voted on them since it's actually the same question you had (at least that's the idea). For this not to be a too-easy-to-get badge, there should be a daily cap of how much daily votes count for this badge, I'm thinking about no more than 2-3 here. And it would need a total of at least 100 of such votes to get this badge. And 'renewing' of votes shouldn't count, meaning: if you vote on a 'new' question and then half a year later unvote and vote again for that question, it shouldn't count as a point for that badge.

I know, that's a lot of conditions and I don't have a catchy name for that, I just feel that an encouraged behavior should be rewarded.

btw. I found this: [Additional Badge Ideas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/additional-badge-ideas)
and read it, after i searched for 'badge idea', but I didn't see a similiar suggestion.

opinions?

Comment: Get rid of your addiction!

Comment: what addiction? that I'm actually doing what's encouraged - searching before posting a new question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Searching before posting a new question isn't the only method of finding ancient questions. Sometimes these old questions are bumped, other times they might be linked in *tangent* to another question's content, and finally you have archive diggers who delve into the depths of their favorite tags. All of these tend to result in votes being accrued.

Then there's the fact that the question can simply not be 3 months old, yet still be discovered by search to avoid duplication. It doesn't have to be ancient to be useful, especially when it comes to new technologies.

There's simply not a strong relation between the behavior you want to encourage (searching before posting a new question) and the behavior you are rewarding (finding old questions that adhere to your fancy).

Comment: I see, good point. The problem essentially is that it's not possible to distinct between a user who searched first and a user who asked the same stupid question and got a link to an old question as an answer, clicking it and thereby "finding" it.

Answer (score 1):

> You've found them by searching and voted on them since it's actually the same question you had (at least that's the idea).

Unfortunately I don't see any way to determine that.

Stack Overflow already has badges for voting on questions/answers:

- Civic Duty
- Electorate
- Sportsmanship

And there is a badge for editing old questions:

- Archaeologist

Why not a badge that rewards upvoting on old questions? Or perhaps adjusting the conditions of an existing badge to account for upvoting old questions?

Ex:

- Explorer
- Miner
- Old-Timer

> Voted on 300 (600?) questions that are over 6 months old

Answer (score 0):

While your intent is good, its next to impossible to use some sort of reward to encourage searching before posting.

On the other hand, perhaps a badge for closing old dupes?  There tons of old questions that are dupes of other old questions that just never got closed as dupes.

Comment: The reason old questions are hard to close is because they don't have much attention. Usually when I strongly think that an old question is a duplicate, I'll flag it for moderator attention