# Is badge request obsolete?

Tags: discussion, badges, obsolete-information

Is the badge request tag obsolete? I saw this because of this question:  [Additional Badge Ideas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/additional-badge-ideas) In fact, during a second glance, I noticed theres a commenting already mention the same thing I am creating a question about. But, I still see no response to his comment. What do you think?

Comment: I take offense with that! :) -- http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/11/taxonomist?user_id=1782

Comment: Well, you can't lose badges unless you are caught cheating... :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find the whole Additional Badge Ideas thread ludicrous ... in fact I'm just about to lock it.

We can not have an intelligent discussion about anything in comments on page 3.

I'm all for one badge request per question. Which is tagged badge-request.

I wish I could just delete that huge badge ideas question, its way too wide.

Comment: Isn't that what we decided earlier? Or was it the giant retag-request thread that got shut down in favour of using separate posts with the appropriate tag?  Regardless, the same thing applies - one proposal per question is much more sane.

Comment: @Ether: it was the tag thing before. I suspect no one took badges seriously.

Comment: Does this mean we should propose our suggestions again, or just leave them in that thread?

Comment: While I'm sad to see that question closed, can you please provide a link from that question to this answer? The comment you left there is too terse.

Comment: @Andy @Andrew, added a comment there ... Locking ... I can not find anything here .. its ridiculous. meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/58700/… If you have real badge suggestions please post them separately as feature requests. If you have less serious ones post them when its Friday in Iceland.