# Aren't you annoyed when you're down-voted while chosen as best answer?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, down-votes

It happens pretty often

- answering
- up rated 1 or 2
- then some other people, for some reasons, just down vote that "best" answer

Isn't it annoying?

Ok, you may close that now :-)

Comment: maybe they feel jealous or maybe they feel that it isn't the best answer and are just frustrated.

Comment: Do you have any specific example/s?

Comment: Pretty often? Only one of your accepted answers on SO has a single downvote.

Comment: Is it an attempt at humour to downvote the question?  It worked on me. :-)

Comment: Can do better...

Comment: @ring0 - what are you expecting in the bounty winning answer? "Yes", "No", a clever argument in favor of this practice or something else?

Comment: Something else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not as annoying as seeing an incorrect answer get heavily up-voted because the voters didn't bother to read it critically or don't know enough about the topic to verify that it's correct.

And it's nowhere *near* as annoying as pointing out a problem with an answer, only to have the author whine about the down-votes he's now receiving instead of putting any effort into improving his work.

Comment: Linked to your point 1, the top answer - with the more votes before acceptance - usually gets even more votes. People do not bother to scroll down to the `0` recent answers at the bottom that are maybe even more relevant. Keep up the good job!

Comment: I'm tempted to downvote this

Comment: You should criticize it first, so that I can preemptively whine about the downvotes.

Answer (score 11):

Not as long as they post a comment stating why they down voted it. Downvotes without justifying comments are always annoying, be it on an accepted answer or not.

And just because the OP accepted an answer, it need not be The Best answer.

Comment: Correct, especially the last statement. Also note that accepting an answer means that it is the most helpful to the OP, which is not the same as most helpful or even correct for everybody else.

Comment: Waiting for this answer to be accepted so I can downvote it :P

Comment: I agree on that - but it happens pretty often on my side... maybe it's just me :-)

Comment: Also, an answer is accepted by whoever asked the question, which in many cases is the person who knows the least about what's going on.  I've seen accepted answers that were actually wrong (and down-voted and left an explanatory comment).

Comment: -1; what you say is true, but you misinterpreted what the OP meant; see @Tobias's answer.

Comment: See [Statler and Waldorf badge for explaining downvotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59162/statler-and-waldorf-badge-for-explaining-downvotes)

Comment: Thanks for the great link. All the best to you.

Answer (score 9):

Yeah. I'm also annoyed when people don't hold doors open for me.

Comment: It's the folks who mosey along in the left lane that annoy me.  (People driving while on the phone don't annoy me so much as frighten me.)

Comment: @David the left lane is where they *should* mosey along. Perhaps you mean the fast lane? :)

Comment: @Philip:  Are you from one of those island countries that drives on the left side of the road?  I don't know that Winston Churchill was ever as insightful as when he said "Two nations, divided by a common language."

Comment: @David I'm just pointing out the importance of abstraction. FastLane can be implemented at runtime by LeftLane or RightLane :)

Comment: @Philip:  I'm not entirely sure any traffic problem can be solved by another layer of abstraction, though.

Answer (score 5):

Downvotes are *supposed* to be "annoying."  If they weren't, people wouldn't pay any attention to them.

If you only received 1 or 2 upvotes before the downvote then I'm sorry to say that your answer is probably wrong, and simply got upvoted by a few people who didn't read the question or answer carefully enough and/or didn't really understand it.  Because to be honest, that particular pattern of votes happens very seldom to many of us.

On the other hand, if I've posted a controversial answer to a subjective question and already received 10 or 20 upvotes, then I would *expect* to see a few downvotes in the mix.  If you never manage to pick up a couple of haters then you're probably just boring everyone half to death.

Just because your answer got a measly 2 upvotes does not mean that it was a good answer.  If you get a downvote under *any* circumstances then man up and check your answer for mistakes or poor writing.  And if you're absolutely sure that your answer is perfect and nobody left a comment, then accept that the world isn't fair and that other people can be frivolous or even stupid.

Welcome to the internet.  Please check your sensitivity at the door.

Comment: Actually I feel pretty good with my `-9` *current* votes :-)

Answer (score 3):

Are you perhaps confusing "best answer", "accepted answer" and "answer with the most upvotes"?

- **best answer**: usually subjectively judged, not measurable on SOFU
- **accepted answer**: the answer the question poster considered the most helpful
- **answer with most upvotes** yeah

I assume you meant the latter, you got two upvotes giving you the lead, when some downvotes changed that. This may be because you have a mistake in your answer (in which case a comment would have been adequate) in which case your answer is definitely *not* the best answer.

But you could also be the victim of *tactical downvoting*, i.e. someone else wanted another answer to get more attention (when viewing sorted by votes).

Unless you point out the an answer that was treated the way you described, there's not much for anyone here to say but speculation ("*link or it didn't happen*")

Comment: It's just that I cannot stand negative numbers. It's why my variables are never called `i`, I'm so afraid there is a `i*i` somewhere.

Comment: @ring0: what about j? engineers prefer that. anyway, you can invert charges to flip signs you don't like :p

Comment: Yes, but the harm is already done ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm annoyed when people don't agree with me, because they're *wrong*. [Ya know](http://xkcd.com/386/).

Comment: They are actually right, like you, they just don't want to agree *with you* :-)

Answer (score 1):

No I'm not annoyed. Sometimes you get downvotes with no clear reason.

It's not worth to be annoyed for. The world has bigger problems.

Comment: Problems like what?