# Should downvote-without-comment rate remain unpublished?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

*Note/update: Within a few minutes/comments/downvotes of posting this question, I accepted an answer and acknowledged in comments that the hypothetical change mentioned was not a good idea. Over the course of the massive downvoting this received, I've also come to better understand the MSO culture, the role of tags and the role of the FAQ and revised this note/update accordingly. I elaborated on the question a bit as well, but tried to stay true to the original.*

I've seen a lot of opinions to the effect that while it's generally a good idea to accompany a downvote with a comment, requiring so would lead to an increase in retaliatory behavior and other problems. I've also seen opinions to the effect that receiving a comment with a downvote is a privilege, not a right.

That said, I'm wondering what the pros and cons are of publishing someones downvote-without-comment rate on their profile. Doing so might discourage such behavior still providing privacy for particular downvotes and therefore not increasing retaliatory behavior. Are there other problems with this that I haven't considered? Is there not a consensus that downvote-without-comment is generally undesirable? I'm really just looking for information/perspectives here. I don't feel I understand the dynamics well enough to actually propose this change at this point.

Comment: touche, first downvoter ;-)

Comment: even if a comment _is_ posted by the downvoter, it doesn't always explain the downvote. Now for the big question: did _I_ downvote you?

Comment: Huh, so now I have a bad-looking number next to my name. I guess I'll post a comment then: Unicorns. And waffles. I hope that helps you!

Comment: Witch-hunting occurs far too often when people try to figure out who downvoted them. Let's not encourage it by publishing a percentage that feeds speculation.

Comment: @JanDvorak - ;-) I suppose it could be gamed in that respect, but I suspect most people downvoting would be hard pressed to say something that was contradictory to how they felt.

Comment: I'm not going to answer this until you get your downvote-comment rate above 80%.

Comment: I can always think of something to say to keep my NCDV ratio low. Such as, "why was this downvoted?"

Comment: @JanDvorak Good point again. On a related matter, do you think that the people downvoting this question (whoever they are ;-) don't realize that the MSO downvote-to-express-disagreement-with-opinion-expressed-in-question is only supposed to apply to feature requests (as documented in http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) or do you think they are aware of it and just choose to ignore the policy?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin Aren't you implicitly making a feature request, i.e. the publication of this rate?

Comment: Wow, that's a provocative and leading title. "Should the number of times you slept with your spouse this week remain unpublished?" "_remain_"?!

Comment: Absolutely not. A feature request implies that I have pretty high confidence that it's something that should be done. As indicated by the question type, I'm seeking feedback and information as part of a discussion.

Comment: @Peter: there's also the fact that this "problem" comes up very, very, very regularly. It gets really trying to read the same "proposals" over and over again and reply with the same objections over and over again. (I.e. the regular downvote reasons do apply here.)

Comment: I may or may not have downvoted this post. (Wouldn't it be really noisy if everybody posted this comment on every post?)

Comment: @Gilles Agreed! I've already accepted (and upvoted!) the answer below.

Comment: @Gilles I had just added something like that to my answer, but you beat me to it. This reminds me of the story of someone leaving a note on a car they bumped into, which reads "other people think I'm leaving my contact information, but I'm really not because I have no intention of paying for the damage."

Comment: @Mat - That's legitimate and it would be reasonable to downvote the question on quality if it was clearly redundant and reflected insufficient effort to see if this is ground that had already been covered. I felt I'd done a reasonable amount of searching/reading on this subject and hadn't seen this idea proposed.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin Your *specific idea* of publishing the rate may or may not have been mentioned, but [encouraging people to explain downvotes by leaving comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135/218097) has been discussed extensively.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Can't blame a guy for trying. Seriously, I try to express legitimate questions about whether to change something or keep it the same in terms of maintaining the status quo, because I think it is less likely to rile people up.

Comment: @JohnBensin What you pointed me too seems to reflect a consensus that comments with downvotes are almost always a good thing and need to be encouraged, with the only debate being over how to best do it. If so, then I don't see the quality issue associated with asking about a specific technique _unless_ that technique has already been discussed. Or am I wrong about there being a consensus on their value?

Comment: I see two things that might explain the downvotes on this question. There's the strongly oriented title, as Josh mentioned. There's also something you may not have known: it used to be that questions showed the “accept rate” of the asker (proportion of their questions where they'd accepted an answer). This led to a huge amount of nagging and pressure to accept answers even when there were no good answers. Accept rate was eventually removed. Introducing something similar sounds like an awful idea. Accepting answers, like comments on downvotes, is good, but the public rate, not so.

Comment: @Gilles Not sure if you were responding to my question to JanDvorak (8th comment down), but I'd really be interested in your thoughts on that. There are obviously lots of reasons to disagree with the proposal mentioned in the question, but that's not what downvotes are supposed to mean for questions other than feature-request.

Comment: When you say it like that, @PeterAlfvin, I understand where you're coming from. Maybe there is no good way to put this idea forward! Still, a bureaucratic "Could there be benefits to publishing...?", something slightly disingenous like "Why can't I view my DV-without-comment rate?", or even a flat "Downvote without comment rate" might come across more neutrally. Then again, they might not... This is not a popular subject.

Comment: What's the point in adding another comment if there's already a good one? Why measure "FGITW" for comments?

Comment: @Flexo Did you intend your comment for another thread? If not, I don't see the relevance here.

Comment: If you're going to measure rates you'd need to consider that it's entirely reasonable to downvote and not add a comment if there's already a good one - otherwise you just encourage overly verbose overuse of comments.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Glad to hear you understand where I'm coming from; I was beginning to doubt my ability to communicate effectively at all. And thanks for the other ideas about how to neutrally ask a question, although I'm pretty skeptical at this point about the title making much difference.

Comment: @Flexo - Thanks. Another excellent point.

Comment: -1, jajfkjsksjsncoajenflodnandosnxosn (I want my 100% rate)

Comment: I downvoted also on the grounds of considering this as not a useful discussion, not just because I disagree with the implicit feature-request. And yeah, "not enough research" kinda fits.

Comment: @JanDvorak I appreciate the feedback. As I said earlier, I thought I'd searched/read quite a bit on this topic (at least within MSO), but I certainly accept that you didn't think I'd done enough.

Comment: +1 for the edit. This may be a case of the [X Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You saw what you perceived to a problem - downvotes without comments - but focused your question on a particular solution. Perhaps, if your research on that root topic left you unsatisfied, you could have asked about it and gotten a more productive discussion.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 Agreed. Lesson learned. :-)

Comment: If you want your rep back, I just found out about a rather unknown feature of the terms of service. You can flag this post and request to have it [disassociated from your account](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-ccwiki). The question will be transferred to an anonymous account and will no longer affect your rep/appear in your profile. Just an option.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 I appreciate the reference, as I do your efforts to document the voting culture and your recent proposal to cap negative question rep. I'm rather proud of the question, though, and am glad to be associated with it in attempts to expose some of the problems I see with the MSO voting culture. Besides, it's "trending better" ;-) and while I really don't care much about MSO rep, I expect it to be a "winner" going forward as it has been recently. :-)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, this should remain unpublished:

Firstly, what would you use a "downvote without comment rate" for? It can't be used for anything positive; it can only be used to persecute people. There are enough baseless accusations that fly around over downvotes already; I don't see what this would do apart from add fuel to the flames. At the worse end of the spectrum it could be used to "justify" retaliation against supposed downvoters.

Secondly, another "rate" is not a good idea, it encourages people to be the "best" at it. It brings us back to the meaningless comment argument:

> redkfjfdkgjhdfkhgdkfjhdfg

Comment: While I agree that it's probably not practical for the reasons stated in the comments, the purpose would be to encourage people to modify their behavior so that they have a "good rate".

Comment: Forcing a comment doesn't mean you get a _good_ comment though @Peter... the rate is just a means to attempt to achieve it. I contend that you can't force people to write good comments though they can easily get a "good" rate.

Comment: I agree you won't always get a good comment. I was just responding to your question of "What would you use [the rate] for?"

Comment: ah yes, good old ["-1 my cat's breath smells like cat food"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59162/statler-and-waldorf-badge-for-explaining-downvotes#comment140845_59165)

Answer (score 12):

Showing a downvote to comment rate will only produce a **negative** affect on users.

*Excessive negativity*

Sometimes it just rather apparent why the downvote occurred. There shouldn't need to be 30 comments all stating the same reason for downvoting. That is what is known as "harpooning". Harpooning is where someone is disciplined so severely in a verbal manner that they are figuratively "harpooned" to the ground. These people will feel very disenfranchised to the community and to those who contributed to the harpooning.

*Positive Reinforcement*

People respond better to suggestions or positive reinforcement than they do to detriments or negative connotations. It would be better to have some sort of pro-active approach to solve the issue of downvoting without commenting. [There are already some of these mechanisms in place.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2373/178816)

*Experts*

There are many experts here who have very little available time and a very large available knowledge base. Some of these experts do not regularly visit the site but when they do and they see something inaccurate they tend to down vote it.

A comment from an expert usually ends up as a lesson (not a bad thing) and it can take them a lot of time to produce the explanation. When the time isn't available to post a lengthy detailed version of what was wrong a downvote will usually suffice.

*For consideration*

To properly implement a feature regarding commenting and downvoting, I think that certain criteria should be considered. Mainly, when is this scenario causing the most confusion? Producing metrics from the worst case scenarios of downvoting without commenting should help ascertain which situations really require feature implementation. One such example could be where someone downvotes every answer and the question without posting an answer or comment of their own, or after deleting a comment or answer they posted.

Comment: Thanks for the response and the reference to the mechanisms in place. I have to say, though, that at least with respect to MSO, I suspect that many of the downvotes are coming from >2k voters expressing agree/disagree on questions other than feature-requests (such as this one ;-)), despite a policy to the contrary. Excluding them from the feedback is somewhat ironic.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin - Meta has its own intricacies for voting that is not really uniform with other exchanges. For the most part I was referring to voting practices on stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Until just a few minutes ago(!) when I experienced what appears to be a small serial-downvote attack, I've had no personal negative experience with downvoting on SO and was motivated more by my MSO experience with questions. The more interesting issue for me on SO is the tradeoff between downvoting and close voting on questions. In the absence of a comment, the latter seems just as easy and provides more information, so I don't understand why it's not always preferable.

Comment: Because you can do both: vote to close *and* downvote. Except in the case of duplicates, or otherwise really good questions that just don't fit our guidelines for whatever reason, I usually downvote the questions I vote to close. Downvotes are how we rate content. Questions that need to be closed as off-topic, impossible to answer, too broad, or otherwise not constructive are not good questions.

Comment: Well, that's not what [Urban Dictionary say about the term "harpooning"](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Harpooning)

Answer (score 6):

I don't see what this would add. You can already see a user's number of downvotes in their profile, and that seems to be enough. I agree with the other comments/answers that it would lead to more witch-hunting as people try to guess who downvoted them.

Also, what about people who downvote and leave a comment *that isn't related to why they downvoted?* Others have already mentioned that people may try to game the rate, but if I downvote, then write a comment in response to another comment, should this still count? It doesn't explain the downvote, but it's *technically* "downvoting and leaving a comment."

Comment: Also I often upvote an existing comment that explains why something deserves a downvote. In this case it would hurt the site to have any behaviour difference between upvoting an existing comment or adding my own roughly identical comment.

Comment: That's a great point, Kate. FWIW, I would consider upvoting a comment to be the same as commenting for purposes of this hypothetical, totally-rejected algorithm, and obviously greatly preferred from a site quality standpoint to adding a near-identical comment.