# Advice on rehabilitating an unpopular Meta question (or not)

Tags: support, specific-question, down-votes, meta

I recently submitted an [MSO discussion question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193762/should-downvote-without-comment-rate-remain-unpublished). In very short order it has been downvoted to the point where it appears on the rogues gallery of downvoted questions (i.e. the last page of questions sorted by votes, with 50 per page). It also has by far the worst net-votes-to-total-views rating of all questions on that last page, which could be worst of all questions. Finally, although I can't see up/down vote totals for other questions with my rep, the fact that the question only has one upvote probably puts it in the running for worst up/down vote ratio amongst high net-downvoted questions.

While there are a few questions on the last page that might cause me to view my membership there as a badge of honor (e.g. [Should we have a policy about "too much downvoting"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42601/should-we-have-a-policy-about-too-much-downvoting)), I would, if possible, like to "improve the question". After all, that's how the system is supposed to work, right? I know I shouldn't radically change the question as that would violate SE's rules of integrity, but wanted to get your thoughts on the reasonableness of any of the following:

- Change the title to fit MSO's convention of highlighting the key change under discussion rather than the twisted form of maintaining the status quo that is there now (ironically done in an attempt to avoid controversy)
- Remove the update about "agreement voting" not being allowed for discussion questions on the grounds that people don't like being lectured to, particularly from a relative newcomer and particularly about something that's been accepted practice for a long time
- Add an update which summarizes all the reasons why the embedded idea was a bad one
- Include a link to the popular [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes) to emphasize that I've read that post as part of my research
- Leave the question alone and let it die, on the grounds that any more modifications at this point would be viewed as pandering and would be considered unwelcome

Comment: Leave the question alone and let it die, on the grounds that any more modifications at this point would be viewed as pandering and would be considered unwelcome

Comment: I think your question is where it is because the change proposed is widely viewed as bad, so without the radical question change you rightly rejected, it will remain extremely downvoted no matter what changes you make. I would leave it alone and chalk it up as a learning experience.

Comment: Thats a surprisingly large number of downvotes on a [meta-tag:discussion], even for Meta. While there was a implicit [meta-tag:feature-request], the response seems overly critical.

Comment: I think the reaction was definitely extreme.  Between the odd phrasing of the title, the implicit feature request, and the edit that appears to read "don't downvote because meta policy says you shouldn't vote for disagreement on discussions", I think that could help explain the negative reaction to the post.

Comment: As a general rule, telling people not to downvote your post makes people want to downvote it that much more.  It just doesn't help.

Comment: I am one of the people who downvoted that question, and I do feel bad that it's become one of the most downvoted questions of the week, and I do think you're a useful contributor here, but I'm not going to change my vote. I don't think I should, my opinion on that question itself hasn't changed. The comments so far have hinted at some of the reasons. Namely, whining about downvotes tends to attract downvotes. But more importantly, I *strongly* oppose anything like what you're suggesting there, and even a whiff of such a feature request is something I'd like to make clear I oppose.

Comment: But it is nothing personal. All of the veteran contributors have made unpopular suggestions that have been heavily downvoted. It's part of the nature of the game. Please don't let it get you down. I don't know that I agree with Robert that any further edits would be "pandering", but it may be best to just let it die anyway. The point is not to get discouraged at participating just because you've made one or two unpopular suggestions. If you want to restore your rep, stick to answering questions where you're in agreement with our customary policies. That's a quick shot in the arm.

Comment: "It also has by far the worst net-votes-to-total-views rating of all questions on that last page..." Nah, don't worry, there are quite a few questions which have 100+ downvotes, they're just not in the list anymore.

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby And they're not in the list because they're ... deleted?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin: No, the list only goes to -50, everything beyond that is hidden...but now that I look for them, seems like the mods have cleaned most of these questions up. Too sad, [but this gem is still here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99062/dont-close-questions-where-the-user-has-requested-that-it-not-be-closed).

Comment: @Cody, can you help me reconcile your statement that you downvoted primarily as an expression of disagreement and you don't think you should remove it with your recent answer about use of the feature-request tag (http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/193943/216381) and you're awareness at this point of the policy against agreement/disagreement voting on anything but feature-requests? Do you really think I mistagged it?  Or is this just a matter of the policy being more of a "guideline" (i.e. Pirate Code type of thing)?

Comment: @Peter I disagree with that policy. I downvote questions with which I disagree. The standing policy about downvotes is that you can cast them for whatever reason one pleases. Top-down attempts to control how the community votes are doomed to failure, and it honestly upsets me that people are trying.

Comment: @CodyGray Interesting use of the term "standing policy". In any event, that last comment from you explains a lot.

Comment: Well, I mean that is the *general* policy on all sites. None of the other FAQs try to tell you for what reasons you can cast up/downvotes. Voting is an anonymous way to indicate your opinion on content. It wasn't until a bunch of people started whining about downvotes on Meta that we added something to the FAQ about it, which was probably a mistake. It allowed us to pretend that we were "codifying" a policy regarding the appropriate use of downvotes, which was dangerous territory. It worked because we were codifying common practice, but won't work when it conflicts with common practice.

Comment: I think downvotes are like incisions with a knife, necessary in certain medical situations, but otherwise just a way to inflict pain. And anonymous votes are the worst as they are cowardly. I wanted to use gunshots as an analogy, pointing to the fact that the state is giving away "free bullets" rather than taxing them, but I couldn't think of any useful purpose for a gunshot to correspond to when I think downvotes do make sense (e.g. incorrect answer).

Comment: I *profoundly* disagree with that characterization. Perhaps that is the root of the problem. I don't think that downvotes are anything like knives, bullets or anything else lethal. I never understood why people take this view of downvotes, yet don't apply the same logic to upvotes. You don't think upvotes should be reserved only for posts to which you want to confer a special reward, do you? No, you just upvote posts that you think are helpful, clear, and useful. So why the higher standard for downvotes? That just leads to vote inflation. I can't balance upvotes by abstaining.

Comment: I use "flag/vote to close" on bad questions because that provides information and is (eventually at least) not anonymous. And as I said, I downvote "wrong" answers on SO if someone else has given the reason in the comments. Otherwise, I'll either make a comment or just support another answer. In any event, the very different standard for upvotes vs. downvotes has to do with the way human beings are wired viz-a-viz positive vs. negative feedback.

Comment: Lots of writers have influenced my thinking about feedback, particularly Deming, but my favorite is David Rock, who has studied and summarized recent brain research. See http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=isiSOeMVJQk for a short intro.

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby I see many items with >-50 net votes (11 at this point in time). If there's filtering or something else going on, I'd like to understand it. Do you happen to know the details?

Comment: @gnat Interesting that the highest upticked comment/suggestion on this question (do nothing) is fundamentally at odds with the highest voted answer on the "dup of" question (edit it). In any event, thanks for the reference. I hadn't thought of the "community wiki" approach.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin: My apologies...I was not aware that those are showing up in the list. Some time ago (last year(?)) everything with a score of -50 or worse was hidden from that list. Seems like they show them again.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin well to me these rather complement each other. I mean, top voted answer explains _theoretically_ correct approach (edit) while top voted comment points to _practical_ risks associated with this (would be viewed as pandering). [Thing is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147282/165773 "as explained in more details here"), '...highly voted posts have a certain appeal that kind of makes you compulsory follow the "majority vote". Despite the edit, question may get downvoted by readers who just follow pack mentality.'

Comment: @gnat Thanks for the follow-up and the reference to your answer in particular, which I frankly had only skimmed previously and now consider particularly thoughtful (and will upvote). :-)