# Can the suffrage badge be achieved multiple times?

Tags: support, voting-badges

Can the [Suffrage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/118/suffrage) badge be achieved multiple times?

The text

> Used all 30 votes in a day

Isn't clear.

Comment: If you click through to the badge-specific page then it's the other way around: it'll say "this badge can be awarded multiple times" on those that can. That isn't included on the badge list summary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is each badge?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-is-each-badge)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No - it can only be awarded once.

**Suffrage**

- bronze; awarded once
- Cast 30 votes on questions and/or answers in a single day

  - Each "day" lasts from midnight UTC to immediately before midnight, UTC; days are not counted in local time
- Originally proposed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/additional-badge-ideas/1264#1264) in June 2009; implemented October 2010.

See this [post here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-is-each-badge/68258#68258) for details on all badges.

Comment: Proposed June 09, implemented Oct 2010 ... thats some big lead time you've got there!