# Can we enable multiple awards for the Suffrage badge?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, voting-badges

The suffrage badge is a new badge that encourages frequent voting (upto the daily cap) for reasons [laid out here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/). The badge can be awarded [only once](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69248/can-the-suffrage-badge-be-acheived-multiple-times).

I have a suffrage badge over on cstheory as do many others, and I noticed a brief uptick in voting when the badge was first introduced (and we posted a system message alerting users to it).

I'd like to request that it be possible to earn the Suffrage badge multiple times. It seems to me that if we want to encourage people to vote more often, it should be an ongoing effort, rather than "I did a 30 vote binge once, and now I get no benefit from voting more often". The example above suggests that we can encourage more votes by highlighting the badge that can be earned, but as a one-time thing it's less effective.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind on awarding this badge for each instance is a user spending a few months to vote on every single post in the entire site, accumulating the maximum number of Suffrage badges. Admittedly, that might be a bit pessimistic. Nevertheless, we want people to vote early and vote often, but also vote responsibly.

Comment: wow ! not that I mind terribly, but I thought question downvotes were for bad questions, not questions people disagree with. alas...

Comment: Well, as it turns out, on Meta people [do downvote out of disagreement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work). It's largely rooted from the fact that highly scored requests are more likely to get implemented, and so reducing the score is a wise move when trying to prevent an idea from being considered. Glad you don't take it personally, though.

Comment: not a problem. I have enough people complaining on cstheory about getting voted down ;)

Answer (score 1):

-1, because that will screw up badge counts too much. Remember that each time you get a badge that can be awarded several times the badge counter in your flair is increased by 1.

I'm not against though having higher tier (silver/gold) badges requiring for example to reach the vote cap for 50 and 150 days.

**EDIT**: in retrospect, we already have [Civic Duty](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/32/civic-duty) so.. I think it's enough badges overall to incentive voting.

Comment: that would be a reasonable compromise.

Comment: @suresh we also have Electorate, not just Civic Duty..

Comment: @jeff if I recall correctly, there's a complicated formula for electorate though, involving ratios of questions and answers. The genius of suffrage is that it's simple, and provides quick gratification: vote 30 times and you're done.

Comment: @suresh but if the goal becomes the badge, then that's a huge negative. The badges are there to teach and to instruct "why does this even exist?"