# Badge Suggestion: "Cubicle Warrior"

Tags: feature-request, fun, badge-request

I know we already have the enthusiast/fanatic/legendary badges, but I'm sure there's a fleet of folks out there that work hard all week and play hard (or simply disconnect) on the weekends.

How about a badge for those folks that are consistently visiting the S[OFUM] sites Monday through Friday? In theory all the enthusiast/fanatic/legendary folks would get this badge(s), but I also know that if the powers that be wanted to work some special logic into this badge, they could.

Comment: Human Verification: "Volksbuch suboby" ...what?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/additional-badge-ideas/48544#48544

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/additional-badge-ideas/1432#1432

Answer (score 1):

Badges are supposed to be used to encourage good behavior; why would SO want to encourage people to be active on the site during the week but not on the weekend?

Comment: Being on the site a lot is "good behaviour", whether or not it happens to be week days or weekends or both. This badge would encourage people who would be unable to gain the Enthusiast or Fanatic badges due to weekend commitments.

Answer (score 1):

Any day of week badges -- "weekend warrior" or its opposite -- are untenable because of local timezone issues. When is your saturday? your sunday? your monday? Might be totally different than mine.

Comment: Yeah you do collect location info in profiles - it would just be a matter of verifying the location maps to a geo-coordinate, if it does grab the timezone and do the offset math from the timezone of the server. If it doesn't then don't offer the badge - no reward for silly or fictional locations.

Comment: @abba I would not exactly call a free text field labeled location, "collecting location info"

Comment: It has the label "location:" - what other sort of info would you presume it collects? The statement I made stands - if they fill it in, and it returns coordinates then why not use em? If you're resistant to the idea that's fine. I was just pointing out that it isn't impossible given the profile info and a little code. I never claimed it wouldn't be more work than it was worth.

Comment: @Abba I poked through [people's locations](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/15690/); the list includes "room", "unversity" (sic), "anywhere mountainous", and "i don't think so", just in the first ~100 results. Not to mention [several dozen URLs](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/15694/). Plus the oddity of this being the only SO feature that uses a user's local time; if this were implemented I'd prefer it just use UTC like the rest of the site to stay consistent

Comment: So if location was changed to a dropdown list with the user specifying a timezone for their location, you could potentially implement the badge that way. I could see some additional benefits such as mapping SO users around the world and doing adjustments to when questions/answers were posted, which I think you've already implemented to some extent.

Comment: the problem with using UTC only is that some users have a large enough offset that it wouldn't be able to determine "weekday" usage as what might be a Friday night for one person may be Saturday using UTC.