# How do I suggest a new Badge?

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request

On stackoverflow I did not see a badge for effective posting, which may apply to your other site that do Q & A.

I think there should be a 'Badge' for n number of times a user references a link to a stackoverflow post that either answers the current question or provides good follow-up information relevant to the answer or implementation.  This would save some space and decrease the number or similar Answers and Answers would be improved via editing.

Comment: Potential problem: How would we keep track? How would we know whether the post actually fits, or is just a post that somebody's spamming links to in order to get the badge? Also, we have facilities for closing questions as duplicates, which covers half of this proposal.

Answer (score 5):

> How do I suggest a new Badge?

Here, on Meta, by asking a question that describes the proposed name of your new badge, what criteria we would use for awarding it, and what purpose it would serve.

> On stackoverflow I did not see a badge for effective posting

I don't know what you mean by "effective posting". We have *lots* of badges for *useful* posts; that's what practically half or more of the badges are about. We're all about content and the system is set up to reward those who post valuable content.

> which may apply to your other site that do Q & A.

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by this either, so I'll throw a couple of different explanations at the wall and hope that one of them will stick:

- Badges are the same across all Q&A sites in the Stack Exchange network, because all sites have the same fundamental goals and purpose.
- Badges are not awarded on one site for participation on another site; each of the sites function basically independently. If that's what you're proposing, [it has been proposed before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57838/cross-site-badges), [on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12603/badge-suggestion-polymath-gold-version-of-generalist) [several](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92138/new-badge-proposal-renaissance-man) [different](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75257/stack-exchange-badges) [occasions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/additional-badge-ideas/38576#38576).

> I think there should be a 'Badge' for n number of times a user references a link to a stackoverflow post that either answers the current question or provides good follow-up information relevant to the answer or implementation.

We already have a series of badges that serve essentially the same purpose:

- [image: Announcer] is a bronze badge for users who shared a link to a question that was visited by 25 unique IP addresses
- [image: [Booster] is a silver badge for users who shared a link to a question that was visited by 300 unique IP addresses
- [image: Publicist] is a gold badge for users who shared a link to a question that was visited by 1000 unique IP addresses

You can see a list of all the available badges on the [Badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) page in the Help Center. (This works for any site, not just Stack Overflow, but like I mentioned above, the list will be the same for all sites.)

> This would save some space and decrease the number or similar Answers and Answers would be improved via editing.

Duplicate answers should not be posted at all. If a question is a duplicate of another question, it should be flagged and closed as such.

Otherwise, there's nothing wrong with *similar* questions and answers. We're not worried about the space, as long as it's used in the service of useful content.

Answer (score 3):

Already have some badges (if I am getting you correctly):

[image: Announcer] Shared a link to a question that was visited by 25 unique IP addresses
 [image: Booster] Shared a link to a question that was visited by 300 unique IP addresses
 [image: Publicist] Shared a link to a question that was visited by 1000 unique IP addresses