# Do community wiki votes contribute to the Sportsmanship badge? Should they?

Tags: support, badges, community-wiki, sportsmanship-badge

The sportsmanship badge is for voting for competing answers. If an answer is a community wiki, is it competing?

Comment: Darn good question.

Answer (score 7):

In the [original suggestion for the sportsmanship badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/additional-badge-ideas/1215#1215), by [gnostradamus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/52738/gnostradamus) and revised by the community, the understanding was that only votes on non CW posts count towards the badge.

However, there is no mention of it in [Jeff's announcement](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/) or in the badge description. I'm assuming it's non CW only, as it would be meaningless otherwise.