# Are upvotes on competing posts counted per question or per answer for Sportsmanship?

Tags: support, badges, sportsmanship-badge

The definition of the [Sportsmanship badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/119/sportsmanship):

> Up voted 100 competing answers

doesn't specify whether each upvote on competing answers to the same question counts towards this criteria, or if it's limited to one "point" per question no matter how many additional competing answers you upvote. Can someone explain how it works?

Comment: Why would it apply to only 1 per answer? I'd be very surprised if it did.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88644/do-community-wiki-votes-contribute-to-the-sportsmanship-badge-should-they/88697#88697

Comment: Follow up question - does it apply if I answer only *after* upvoting?

Comment: @Leeor [It doesn't matter whether you upvote before or after answering](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68156/191706), as long as your answer gets a positive score.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the question has 3 answers, including your own, you have up to 2 chances to upvote competing posts.  This assumes your answer has a score of at least 1.

Comment: Do the answers have to be non-CW? How are Community Wiki posts handled when counting votes on competing answers?

Comment: @beam022 It doesn't say anything in the badge description about CW answers, so I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 6):

*Competing answers* are all the answers but yours, given for the same question.