# How does the sportsmanship badge logic work?

Tags: support, badges, sportsmanship-badge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are upvotes on competing posts counted per question or per answer for Sportsmanship?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105637/are-upvotes-on-competing-posts-counted-per-question-or-per-answer-for-sportsmansh)

I'm a bit confused about the details of the sportsmanship badge, and when I searched on meta to try and clarify the issue I found conflicting information.

- The accepted answer on [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93144/do-sportsmanship-badge-votes-count-after-an-answer-is-accepted) makes it clear that you would need 100 answers with a positive score, and an upvote on some other answer in that question.
- The [unofficial FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) on this topic makes it clear that you would need only 100 upvotes on other answers, where you had an answer with a positive score, i.e. you would not necessarily need 100 answers.  You could vote on 2 other answers to the same question, for example.

They seem to be mutually exclusive, so which is correct?

Comment: Rick just updated his answer to the other according to the dupe, invalidating mine.  The second interpretation, the one in the FAQ, looks to be correct.

Comment: Good point.  I've edited the first answer you linked to match the wording of the FAQ.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88644/do-community-wiki-votes-contribute-to-the-sportsmanship-badge-should-they/88697#88697