# Badge Suggestion: Pinpoint Accuracy

Tags: feature-request, badge-request, daily-reputation-limit, daily-reputation-badges

I suggest a badge that would be awarded (one time only) for achieving EXACTLY 200 reputation in a single day.  Votes above that would disqualify the user from achieving the badge; they should not have any "wasted" reputation.  I'd also suggest disqualifying bounties from the consideration for this badge; otherwise a +200 bounty would make it too easy to hit.

Comment: Isn't the purpose of rep and badges to encourage people to participate?  I feel like this would actively discourage people to participate after a certain point.

Comment: There is already a badge for the first time you hit the rep cap. I don't see any need to have a badge for gaining 200 points in a day.

Comment: Always ask yourself "What positive behavior is this encouraging?"

Comment: You just want it because you've done it six times.

Comment: @Conrad: I had no idea I'd done it six times, but good to know!  Actually, it just seemed like an interesting point of efficiency; i.e. how can I put as much effort into SO as possible without wasting any.

Comment: Get 200+ points. Post retarded stuff and get downvoted to 200 points. Why? Consecutive 200+ points per day or something would be more useful, wouldn't it?

Comment: Others have already hinted at this, but I'm honestly curious about why you think this badge would be a good idea. What sort of behavior would this encourage? Why should we give out badges for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Additional Badge Ideas](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/additional-badge-ideas)

Comment: @CodyGray: Achieving rep is tricky; some effort is (sometimes) required to achieve 200 rep.  The badge would honor those who have put in enough effort to achieve 200 rep, and have not expended "wasted" effort.  Because it would be hard to achieve precisely 200 reputation in a day, it would encourage repeated attempts at getting 200 reputation in a day, without being "showboatish".

Comment: Sure, I get that. It's hard to reach the rep cap every day. That's why there are badges for it. First, you get the "Mortarboard" badge for the first time you hit the rep cap. Then, you can earn the "Epic" badge for hitting the rep cap 50 times, and the "Legendary" badge for hitting the rep cap 150 times. I'm not saying that we shouldn't reward people who do this. I'm curious as to why you think that we should award badges for the small segment of people who happen to earn 200 rep in a day *and* give that as a bounty. They're already getting two things for their efforts: badges, and answers.

Answer (score 2):

**No.  This doesn't encourage any positive behavior.**  Further I think it would encourage the paraniod questions -- why did I get downvoted in the last second of the day??  This friggin Troggy user didn't like my idea and just wanted to prevent me from getting my badge.

Comment: By the way, if you can figure out any ways to *discourage* the whining about downvotes, please post it as a new `[feature-request]`. kthx :-)