# League Result Badge (Repeatable)

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request

I was really surprised that there are no league based badges on the Stack Exchange sites. I think that ranking in a certain level in the leagues would make for an excellent repeatable badge. I am aware that someone ranking in a significant place is already getting the rep for it, and if that is enough, I am totally happy with that. I am actually using the Stack Overflow site to learn more than anything through answering - but it seems a strange omission.

I would have thought that Stack Exchange would have some sort of badge for one of the following:

- A bronze badge awarded for being in the top 250 rep gains per week/month etc
- A silver badge awarded for being in the top 50 ....
- A gold badge for being in the top 10

Or looking at it from a different angle:

- A bronze badge awarded for Monthly Top 10
- A Bronze Badge awarded for Quarterly Top 10
- A Gold Badge awarded for Yearly Top 10

I did manage to find [Additional Badge Ideas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/additional-badge-ideas) but it is locked. I'm not sure if that means that Stack Exchange isn't accepting any new ideas for badges (there certainly are LOADS of topics on Meta for badge suggestions), and this is probably more of a *Why was this omitted as there are so many other badges* rather than a *can I, can I, can I* post.

I would find it hard to believe that the folks who come up with this exchange didn't come across this idea.

Edit: Would it be possible to show (either private or public) the best result for each of the leagues for that user on their profile page?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Badges are here to encourage positive behaviour. Getting in the top X is fun, but it is no goal for the site. Besides being in the top X is a reward in itself. So no need for another badge.